# Новостной сайт. Выбор CMS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, joomla

Всем доброго времени суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста - стоит задача сверстать новостной сайт (верстать буду руками, без консрукторов) и затем, чтоб посты из Facebook автоматически постились на сайте. (!!!) Важно, не наоборот, а из FB на сайт, а не с сайта на FB (!!!)

Может кто сталкивался с такими вещами, подскажите, на какую CMS лучше посадить такой сайт и может поможете статьями, видеоуроками какими-то.
Заранее благодарен.

Говорю сразу, что гуглил. Остановился пока что на Joomla. Но речь конкретно о том, чтоб новости публиковались из Фейсбука. А, сайт отдаю клиенту и сам его вести не буду, т.е. обязательно нужна CMS'ка. Хотя, если есть решение без CMS и можно как-то настроить такой автопостинг, то с удовольствием от CMS откажусь

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, по собственному опыту скажу - не стоит использовать Joomla и Wordpress если не собираетесь обновлять их как только выходят обновления, что вы делать не собираетесь, так как передадите клиенту, а он скорее всего не будет компетентен в данном вопросе. Иначе огромен риск столкнуться с [такой же проблемой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666697/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0). Сам сталкивался. Проще оказалось снести сайт и делать на другой CMS, с тех пор очень недолюбливаю WP. Joomla имеет аналогичные проблемы.

А вот в качестве альтернативы им - могу предложить [MODX Revolution](https://modx.com/download). Там уже не столько CMS, сколько CMF - по сути еще не было задач, которые бы я не смог на ней решить. Да и ни разу её не взламывали, хотя используем в основном только её, изредка bitrix (но он платный). У неё есть и плагины. В отличие от WP и Joomla их нужно будет настраивать в коде (у CMS есть свой шаблонизатор, но можно подключить и такие как smarty или fenom), но зато это дает некую гибкость и после одной настройки вы уже будете знать как что работает и в следующий раз проблем возникнуть не должно.

Для кроспостинга есть плагин [mSocial](https://modstore.pro/packages/alerts-mailing/msocial) и для Facebook к нему [mSocialFB](https://modstore.pro/packages/alerts-mailing/msocialfb) - он платный, 190р, но никто не мешает вам разобраться как это все работает и добавить этот функционал самому (хотя, времени может уйти больше, раз вы не знакомы с MODX).

Если заинтересовало - тогда могу дальше посоветовать что лучше использовать и что почитать, но пока почитайте просто [что это за "оно"](http://promo-creative.com/10-prichin-vyibrat-modx-revolution.html) (тут просто перечислены преимущества, думаю более подробную информацию сможете найти сами).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Тут больше зависит от предпочтения заказчика (имею в виду CMS), но я думаю, что он не будет противю. Я, кстати, наслышан про MODx, но всегда пугает эта "посадка", так-как я не очень в php. Если можете дать какой-то урок/статью по тому как посадить, к примеру, секцию статей каких-то или что-то типа этого на MODx, буду крайне благодарен.

Comment: Вообще, там желательно для понимания сперва разобраться что такое шаблоны\чанки\сниппеты\ТВ, тогда уже будет проще, нежели сразу лезть лепить что-то, не знакомясь с CMS. В принципе, по ней уже довольно большая документация в рунете. Есть и гайды. Вот к примеру один из них - с самого нуля http://modx.ws/blog/uroki-modx-revolution/