# Wp vcd атака, когда нет нулевых плагинов

Tags: wordpress, уязвимости

Мой сайт сегодня взломали с помощью Wp vcd (добавился код в functions.php темы, пользователь не добавился). Я прочитал что это такое, но не понял как они это сделали. У меня нет ни одного нулевого плагина. Тема одна, самописная, остальные удалены.

В какой-то статье про эту атаку увидел, что плагин Yoast SEO в версии 5.7.1 имеет xss уязвимость, и у меня как раз он стоял. Но как можно через xss добавить php код? Тем более, xss уязвимость была в админке.

Еще интересно, в чем смысл этой атаки?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Зачем Вам ? собираетесь сайты взламывать ? весь написанный вами сценарий более похож на сказку. Где-то прочитали о способах атаки, и пытаетесь здесь узнать детали, как это осуществить ? Вообще запретил бы на месте админов обсуждение таких тем.

Comment: Вот тут https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81-wp-vcd-malware/ @SeVlad отвечал, как вычистить. А как взломали - сразу не скажешь. Возможно, дырка раньше была, и через неё давно внедрили код. И только сейчас он стал активно себя вести. Возможно, на shared хостинге ошибка безопасности, и залезли с соседнего сайта.

Comment: Digital Core, я знаю что такое вордпресс и работал с разными фреймворками, но поскольку у вас нет бизнес-ориентированного отношения, вам не понять почему я использую его. И вообще, это не в тему. А если вам так трудно понять зачем мне это, обясню. Откуда уверенность, что то же самое не сделают сегодня или завтра???

Comment: Когда пишете кому-то, ставьте @ перед именем. Ну а в целом, где-то вы допустили оплошность. У меня десятки сайтов на WP, ни один не был взломан.

Comment: @SeVlad отлично) пусть обломает зубы)))

Comment: @KAGGDesign сольётся - 100%. Как и все кулцхакеры, кому я это уже много раз предлагал.  :)

Comment: На SO я тоже отвечал ;) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-wordpress/777040#777040

Comment: @DigitalCore :) Да, я такой дурак, что таким как ты пытаюсь вправить мозг. Так что, отвечаешь - ты не ботан?

Comment: @DigitalCore >твой WP даст rood доступ через header, если не дурак
Ну ты же не дурак? - давай вставишь в "мой" ВП. Или таки дурак? Если не вставишь - с тебя 100$. Если вставишь - С меня 200$. Идёт?

Comment: @DigitalCore "твой WP даст rood доступ через header" - что это за бред? И что такое `rood` - доступ? С таким знанием английского лучше в полемики не ввязываться )

Comment: @DigitalCore ну хамить ты тут первый начал. Думаю, это не пройдет мимо модераторов. Твой камент про дурака я тревогой отметил.

Comment: @DigitalCore, о, дядя, нашелся.. Я думаю, что когда тебя папа должен был учить быть мужиком и отвечать за свои слова  я уже деньги в семью зарабатывал. Так что, дядя, отвечаешь за свои высеры, или спишем на сырые подгузники блондинки?

Comment: @Miqayel первое, вы правильно подметили `разобраться самому`, то есть не доверяйте кому либо чистить вашу систему, движок. Дам несколько ссылок полезных в вашем случае: 1) https://medium.com/@cirku17/wp-vcd-malware-analysis-7c5dbaad89c3  2) https://github.com/rakshitshah94/wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-solution Но не забывайте об используемой версии `php` и `sql` так, как в большинстве случаев именно это причина инъекций.  Конечно это не гарантирует вам полную безопасность  так как можно: 1) https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ddos-low-and-slow-attack/ и много ещё всего ....