# Как отследить вызов функций в WP

Tags: wordpress, вирусы

Помогите пож с такой задачей. Есть сайт, на нем возможно есть вирус, который заливает файлы. По логам проходят такие вот строчки типа:

```
85.203.47.46 - - [04/Jun/2018:11:44:35 +0300] "GET /index.php/en/ HTTP/2.0" 200 7577 "https://ktc-china.com/index.php/ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15"
```

а следом идут боты поисковика и пытаются проиндексировать

```
66.249.66.211 - - [04/Jun/2018:11:47:36 +0300] "GET /upload/video/thumbs/small/2015/02/26/74bdd60f6635.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2721 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
```

Уже все файлы пересмотрел, но найти не могу где и как получается попадает зловред на сайт. Как можно отследить какая функция вызывается и заливается на сайт?!

Comment: См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-wordpress/777040#777040

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте один из плагинов безопасности, например, [Wordfence](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/). просканируйте сайт. Плагин сам найдёт изменения в файлах ядра или плагинов из репозитория. Выдаст сообщения, если найдёт вирусный код.

В дальнейшем плагин самостоятельно будет производить сканирование сайта по расписанию и отправку уведомлений об обнаруженных проблемах администратору.

Comment: плагин стоял, но ничего не нашел. айболитом сканировали, но он тоже находит файлы, которые не заражены

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что есть проблема? файл `/upload/video/thumbs/small/2015/02/26/74bdd60f6635.jpg` не должен существовать?

Comment: ну да) это левый какой то файл. вот еще как пример 213.59.188.60 - - [03/Jun/2018:16:29:42 +0300] "GET /images/users/avatars/small/5ac8db1fda03cdc092f0bf1d20e80554.jpg HTTP/2.0" 200 1956 "https://dokonlin.ru/video/pole-razuma-2-sezon-2-serija-psihodelich.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" . не сущ файлы отдают 200 код

Comment: Трудно так сказать, в чем дело. Надо копать на сервере. Попробуйте для начала снести все php файлы, залить папки WordPress из официального источника, потом установить заново все плагины и темы из репозитория.

Comment: вот был, как отследить вызов функций, а не как удалить вирус)))

Comment: Каких функций? Их неимоверно количество в WP. Код занимает полмиллиона строк. О чем вопрос? Такой надо закрывать, как too broad.