# WordPress заражен вирусом

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на WordPress перестал нормально работать. Не могу обновить запись и страницу, не могу найти приложения в магазине. Как будто что-то блокирует высылку запроса.
Подскажите, как найти вредоносный код и как обезопасить себя от таких атак на WordPress.

Comment: Предложить работу соответствующему специалисту

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемма была в плохом хостинге.