# Как запретить переход по внешней ссылке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, frontend

Время от времени, когда нажимаешь на публикацию, пользователя кидает на какой-то левый сайт. Сделал анализ внешних ссылок, там ничего не выявилось. Если есть какой нибудь плагин, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777040/220220

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вирусы в WordPress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-wordpress)