# Как найти и почистить сайт от вирусов?

Tags: wordpress

На сайте появились вирусы, сайт на WP. Проверял на онлайн сканере Dr.Web пишет (Сайт находится в базе вредоносных сайтов Доктор Веб), подскажите кто в курсе как найти и почистить вирусы?

Comment: Проще пересоздать сайт с нуля

Comment: Нет не проще.....

Comment: Проще, потому что все следы от вирусов по всему сайту вы очень вряд ли вычистите

Comment: Поставьте плагин WordFence, проведите сканирование. Замените файлы, на которые он укажет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте плагин Wordfence Security - [офиц. сайт](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/), мне он отлично помог в свое время. Бесплатных аналогов этому замечательному плагину я не нашел.