# Несанкционированние создание администратора на сайте Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, безопасность, взлом, вирусы

На сайте Wordpress злоумышленник создал учетную запись администратора. Регистрация на сайте была отключена, а по Activity Log все выглядело так, будто учетная запись была добавлена из админки, но НЕ от имени супердамина, а словно бы появилась сама собой. Очевидно, это взлом, или где-то был зашит бэкдор, но как его найти? По словам владельца, на сайте не использовались пиратские компоненты, но сайт обслуживался несколькими админами до этого, может быть кто-то "подложил свинью".

Загуглил почту этого нового "админа", оказалось, что не так давно такие же учетные записи появились и на других сайтах Wordpress. Вот, например: https://disquy.com/community/activity/nikolas1988i-ua/ и https://www.motivatingafrica.com/community/profile/nikolas1988i-ua/ Подскажите, пожалуйста, где копать? И как вообще Wordpress можно проверить на уязвимости? Пробовал https://rescan.pro, но он никаких проблем не выявил. Права на файлы установлены правильно, логины-пароли с ухода старых админов менялись, но в любом случае, "левый" админ появился из ниоткуда, с существующей учетной записи на сайт никто не заходил.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-wordpress/777040#777040

Comment: @SeVlad Спасибо! Это все было сделано в первую очередь. Онлайн-сканеры (не только от revisium, та же sucuri и другие) показывают, что все чисто. Айболит, конечно, показал кучу красных и желтых файлов. Я фильтровал ложные срабатывания так: собрал чистый сайт с теми же компонентами (из каталога ВП), и результаты сканирования были одинаковы. Может быть есть что-то вроде... теста на SQL-инъекции или какие-то другие уязвимости? Просто ума не приложу, где копать.

Comment: @SeVlad На почищенном сайте пока никто не появился, но все равно хотелось бы вычислить причину точную, так как компоненты остались те же самые, если уязвимость в них, то этот "николас" опять может появиться. Все же это даже не спам-ссылки, а административная учетка.

Comment: Я потратил всего несколько минут, чтобы загуглить ник этого мамкиного хакера и выявил одну закономерность у "зараженных" сайтов: плагин wpForo.

Comment: В WordPress нет известных  уязвимостей. Дыры обычно в непонятно откуда взятых или "нулленых" плагинах и темах. Найти эти дыры можно антивирусным ПО, например, плагином Wordfence, имеющим миллионы установок. Поиск проблем извне, как делает rescan, - это просто ни о чём. Как можно найти вирус или троян, не сканируя исходный код php - файлов и не сравнивая контрольные суммы известных файлов, например, ядра? Так работает Wordfence.

Comment: Для того, чтобы завести админа, существует масса способов, и для этого не надо заходить на сайт. Бэкдор в плагине может предоставить такую возможность с помощью php-кода.

Comment: @StackGuest все причины перечислены по ссылке. В большинстве случаев дыры находятся в темах и плагинах не из оф. каталога

Comment: @noname228 нет, такого плагина на сайте не установлено. Собственно, это вообще сайт-визитка, без форума и даже без регистрации пользователей.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Wordfence попробую, спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ничего не показал Wordfence, кроме нескольких измененных CSS-сок (которые я сам менял под дизайн). Может есть какой автоматизированный pen-test на сам сайт или на сервер? Я гуглил эту тему, но... кхм, опасаюсь, может там скрипт сливает уязвимости автору и потом он сам еще взломает сайт...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть кому-то пригодится: дело было в плагине ConvertPlus, уязвимость позволяла создать админа через форму подписки на рассылку https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/9325

Comment: Пп 1.2, 2.1 и 3.4 в моей ссылке :) (*всё сделано в первую очередь, угу*)

Comment: @SeVlad И? После взлома сайта он был пересобран с нуля, как я и написал (по сути, все пункты и были выполнены). Но эта инструкция никак не помогла установить причину взлома, Айболит кроме кучи ложных срабатываний ничего внятного на скомпрометированной версии не показал. Спасибо WPScan и их базе уязвимостей, вот они отработали, как надо.