# Неубиваемый вирус WP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Чищу сайт от вирусняка, после массового взлома через adminer. Что-то постоянно меняет адрес сайта в БД на вредоноса и файл .htaccess.

Пытался полностью зачищать домашнюю директорию на хостинге через `rm -rf *` и ставить чистую установку WP с чистой БД без всяких доп плагинов. Буквально через 2 минуты после установки происходит заражение и при этом в access логе ничего подозрительного нет.

При этом - если ставить не WP, в ту же директорию, то никаких заражений не происходит.

Не нашел в гугле ни у кого подобных проблем. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Похоже, что заражён весь хостинг, и вирус прилетает изнутри.

Comment: Что за хостинг используете? WP оффициальной версии?

Comment: @MoloF шаред хостинг от nic.ru. WP с оф. сайта последний

Comment: Бежать с этого говнохостинга, чистить ПК и читать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040

Comment: А заливаете на хостинг чем? Есть ненулевая вероятность, что вирус сидит у вас на компе и перехватывает ftp-сеансы

Comment: Захожу по SSH и с помощью `wget` дергаю последнюю сборку wp с оф сайта. Да и на компьютере у меня линукс, а не винда, что немного снижает вероятность вируса

Comment: Если вы умеете по ssh ходить -- возьмите нормальный хостинг, где есть гит или можно поставить. И заходя делайте тупо git clone и потом git pull для забора изменений. И видеть вирусы будете влёт и легко будет одной командой почистить все вирусы.

Answer (score 0):

Чистый wp без плагинов всегда достаточно хорошо проверен, как правило ломают через плагины. Поэтому совет всегда "ставьте самую свежую версию без плагинов" вполне нормальный.

Советов по вашей конкретной ситуации два.

Во-первых, перейдите уже на версионный контроль!!! Установка wp должна быть не на хостинг -- а на свой компьютер, чистый от вирусни. И тут же сделать снимок файлов, чтобы иметь возможность быстро одной командой откатить все файлы в положение, как в репозитории.

Второй совет: поменяйте сервер, похоже у вас весь шаред заражён или просто один из сайтов попал в базы wp-сайтов.