# Как определить бесплатную тему от платной на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Я совсем новичок и хочу понять как отличать платные темы от бесплатных на WordPress? подскажите на что смотреть.

Comment: Если коротко, за платные нужно платить деньги. Это бросается в глаза.

Comment: Это логично! а фильтров там нет что бы сортировать.

Comment: Там это где?...

Comment: на их сайте/портале https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/

Comment: В официальном каталоге все темы бесплатные, кроме тех, что находятся в разделе "Коммерческие темы" https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/commercial/

Comment: вот ссылка на саму тему https://populariswp.com/popularis-star/

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтепа кнопочка «Free Download» ни о чём не говорит?

Comment: Если вы можете свободно скачать тему с сайта разработчика, значит бесплатная, но поддержки от них не ждите.

Comment: Кнопочка говорит о многом, я переживаю что в низу сайта написано free trial ((

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтепа Это не про тему, это демо-контент, не обращайте внимание

Comment: Понял, Неолит спасибо тебе!

Comment: @Neolot подскажи как ее установить в качестве постоянного шаблона на вордпресс? в админке-внешний вид-темы она вроде бы стоит по умолчанию как основная, но почему в низу сайта написано trial? как это убрать, может я поставил версию pro? как узнать? вот ссылка на сам сайт где стоит эта тема. https://spicynuts.ru/

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтепа Просто удалите этот блок

Comment: так просто!))) я даже не подумал об этом! Спасибо! к сожалению не могу понять как Вас отблагодарить путем поднятия рейтинга.

Comment: Пожалуйста!....

Comment: @Neolot, может уже соберёшь комментарии в ответ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтепа Оформил свои комментарии в ответ. Отметьте его как решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: Прежде чем качать непоми откуда непойми что читай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Визуально, на глаз, определить платная тема или нет довольно легко. На странице платных тем есть кнопка "Купить", а на бесплатных это кнопка для скачивания.

В официальном каталоге Wordpress все темы бесплатные, однако есть раздел ["Коммерческие темы"](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/commercial/), где разработчики предлагают услуги за плату. У одних может быть плата за доступ, у других — членские взносы, а третьи могут предоставлять темы бесплатно и брать деньги только за поддержку.

Если же в демо бесплатной темы вы увидели упоминание об оплате, то скорее всего это просто демо-контент для демонстрации возможностей темы.

Comment: > раздел "Коммерческие темы". ....
На самом деле там ссылка не на **коммерческие темы**, а на **производителей** . См   там текст: "Ниже представлен список компаний, предоставляющих GPL-темы с дополнительными платными услугами.". Заголовок страницы неправильный. И надо написать что в репо все темы бесплатные. Про платный демо-контент первый раз слышу. Это где  такое?

Comment: > И надо написать что в репо все темы бесплатные. Я так и написал) Платного демо не бывает, наверно. Автор вопроса увидел в демо текст про триал и подумал, что тема триальная.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Вопрос закрыл, почистил подвал как и посоветовали, удалил ссылку!