# Сarbon Fields не сохраняет значение картинки

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины, интернет-магазин

Я осваиваю Carbon Fields и столкнулся с проблемой. В миниатюре не сохраняются картинки. При этом в PHPMyAdmin-таблицах картинка есть. 
[image: До]
[image: После]

[Видеоурок](https://youtu.be/2wIEC5WSLaY?list=PLzFj4L-LMRzt5BsX_ho5rt5hCc5ynnReu&t=1590), по которому писал код
Код в подключённом файле:

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;

Container::make( 'theme_options', __( 'Настройки темы' ) )
    ->set_icon( 'dashicons-carrot' )
    ->add_tab( __( 'Profile' ), array(
        Field::make( 'select', 'est_header_logic', __('Использовать логотип?'))
                ->add_options(array(
                      'yes' => 'Использовать логотип',
                      'no' => 'Использовать текст',
                )),
        Field::make( 'image', 'est_header_logo', __('Логотип') )
            ->set_value_type('url')
            ->set_conditional_logic(array(
              'relation' => 'AND',
              array(
                  'field' => 'est_header_logic',
                  'value' => 'yes',
                  'compare' => '=',
              )
            )),
        Field::make( 'text', 'est_header_site_name', __( 'Название сайта' ))
            ->set_conditional_logic(array(
              'relation' => 'AND',
              array(
                  'field' => 'est_header_logic',
                  'value' => 'no',
                  'compare' => '=',
              )
            )),
        Field::make( 'text', 'est_header_site_desc', __( 'Описание сайта' ))
            ->set_conditional_logic(array(
              'relation' => 'AND',
              array(
                  'field' => 'est_header_logic',
                  'value' => 'no',
                  'compare' => '=',
              )
            )),
    ) )
    ->add_tab( __( 'Notification' ), array(
        Field::make( 'text', 'crb_email', __( 'Notification Email' ) ),
        Field::make( 'text', 'crb_phone', __( 'Phone Number' ) ),
    ) );
```

Comment: Лучше взять что-то живое, чем препарировать трупы https://wordpress.org/plugins/carbon-fields/. А картинки надо вставлять в тело вопроса.

Comment: Последние изменения на гите 16 дней назад) не такой уж и труп)

Comment: @WPPunk не знаю что там на гите, но раз выкинут из репо, значит там в 99% случаев зараза. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040 п1.4. Нет смысла такое осваивать -  есть куча нормальных аналогов.

Comment: Carbon Fields одна из топовых библиотек для создания полей, если вы ее не используете, не надо тут советы раздавать)

Comment: @WPPunk во первых если ты хочешь чтобы твой коммент прочёл тот, к кому обращаешься - его надо пингануть. Во вторых - не надо мне указывать что кому советовать. Я советую пойти правильным путём и не допустить непоправимую ошибку. *У грамотных есть  железное правило: если чего-то не тет в репо - используй на свой страх и риск. Остаться без помощи сообщества в тч.*

Comment: @SeVlad половина packegist нет в репозитории, не юзать теперь?)

Comment: @WPPunk на знаю про какую половины ты толкуешь - я почему-то обхожусь без неё. Но на бис: "на свой страх и риск". Акцентирую - **на свой**, а не советовать нубам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже у CF была подобная [проблема](https://github.com/htmlburger/carbon-fields/issues/624).

Попробуйте обновить CF до текущей версии через `composer require htmlburger/carbon-fields`

Если не поможет, то уберите `set_value_type('url')` у изображения. Теперь вместо url в поле будет храниться id, через который можно получить url.

```
$imgId = carbon_get_theme_option( 'est_header_logo' );
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($imgId, 'full');
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы оказались правы. После изменения версии всё заработало