# Помощь в установке плагина WP Siema Slider для Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Данный плагин не устанавливается стандартной установкой плагинов в Wordpress. Выдаёт ошибку архива.
Ручная установка скриптов и добавление кода в functions.php темы выводит шорткод с ошибкой "в данной категории ничего не найдено". Изменение категории ничего не даёт.
Создание новой записи\слайда с "Siema Sliders" post type, как написано в описании плагина невозможно. Данного типа записи не существует.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с установкой плагина.
[WP Siema Slider Plugin for Wordpress](https://github.com/bpolack/WP-Siema-Slider)

Comment: Может обратиться к разработчикам плагина? Вот только я бы не стал рисковать и ставить плагины. которых не смог разыскать в https://wordpress.org/plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ручная установка скриптов и добавление кода в functions.php темы
> выводит шорткод с ошибкой "в данной категории ничего не найдено".

Не понятно что и зачем понадобилось прописывать в functions.php, но по ссылке с гитхаба нужно взять только каталог `dist`, и, переименовав, его в `wp-siema-slider` залить в каталог плагинов. После этого активировать. Если плагин написан правильно, то всё получится.

Однако ставить то, что не находится в [оф. репо](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)- довольно рискованно. См [Вирусы в WordPress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040). Тем более что плагинов для слайдеров - как грязи.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. По поводу рекомендаций спасибо, но ничего лёгкого и быстрого в каталоге плагинов WP для того, чтобы вывести товары в слайдер, нет. Либо урезанные возможности, либо тяжёлые. А дальше ценник за слайдер $50 и привет.

Comment: @Стас а как на счет вывода товаров используя уже существующие шорткоды и slick slider? В чем проблема?

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Даже в голову не пришло! Поковыряв siema slider и оценив риски решил отказаться от него.