# Form Filter нужна документация, помогите!

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, нужна помощь с поиском документации для это плагина. Такое ощущение, что гугл меня просто забанил. Если у вас нет документации, но вы работали с Form Filter,отпишитесь в комментариях пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с проблемой(

Comment: У плагина должен быть оф. сайт или как минимум разработчик, что должно быть видно на странице плагинов.

Comment: @SeVlad, ничего нигде не написано)

Comment: Если это действительно так (что маловероятно), значит это непонятно чей самопис. Вам должно быть виднее где вы его взяли. И см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040