# Защита от взлома сайта на wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, взлом

Есть сайт на WP, расположен на самодельном хостинге (на базе OpenServer) неиспользуемые порта закрыты.
Наблюдается проблема, сайт через каждые час - два, заражается посредством добавления сторонних php файлов, также происходят редиректы на посторонние сайты. Неиспользуемые плагины и темы удалены, на сайте только 2 плагина, Classic Editor, ACF Pro (купленный). .htaccess - дефолтный. Как убезопасить себя в дальнейшем??

Что было мною сделано:

1. Замена каталогов и файлов wp - на скачанные с офф сайта (кроме папки с темой и wp-config.php);
2. Вычищена гадость из wp-config.php
3. Просмотр настроек сайта на странице wp-admin/options.php и удаление из бд настроек которые не относятся к сайту.
4. Выпилен плагин ACF и заменен на более старый (он взломан, я прекрасно понимаю что это - потенциальная дыра, и это не ест хорошо - но заказчик не желает платить за лицензию) - старый плагин работает на нескольких сайтах - ни единой проблемы, из вышеперечисленных.
5. Слегка изменен .htacces (добавлено ограничение на количество авторизаций).
6. Заново созданы FTP доступа.
7. Сама тема состоит из хедера, футера и главной страницы, там даже functions.php отсутствует. Тему писал сам, пересмотрел, там ничего левого нет.
8. К сожалению последовать совету и хоститься где-то еще - не позволяет:

   - Желание сэкономить и чтобы не платить за радио-хостинг (сайт - интернет-радио).
   - Весьма специфичный софт который не на всех серверах накатишь.
9. После этого, последовал советам в комментах, облазил логи за три дня, позакрывал все ip (блокировал полностью подсети, то есть от .1 до .225).

После этого вирусных файлов  и кода я больше не видел, правда .htaccess все равно кто-то модифицирует. Позакрывать IP для входу в админку увы невозможно так как у заказчика и менеджера адреса динамические. Повесил авторизацию через .htaccess

Comment: Нанять специалиста в даннном вопросе. У вас вирус либо в базе уже сидит, либо в файлах, которые вы не до конца вычищаете. Возможно, что заражение идёт извне, от других файлов на хостинге вне сайта. Сайт должен быть изолирован.

Comment: 1. Читать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777040. 2. Избавляться от виндонеосерверов. Они не для того чтобы открывать на них сайты из вне. (и вообще не для разработки сайтов на ВП)

Comment: я так думаю у вас не только добавяются новые файлы но так же уже заражено и ядро wp вы проверяли все ядро на наличие измененных файлов js и php? о базе уже писали выше

Comment: То, что плагин работает на других сайтах и там всё хорошо - это ни о чём. Аргумент уровня "у меня сосед двери не запирает, его пока ещё не обокрали, я тоже не буду". Посмотрите журналы сервера, на POST запросы, которые по времени совпадают со временем создания новых файлов. Так и отследите дыру. И вы ничего не написали про защиту админки. Надеюсь вы ограничили её по IP только для администраторов сайта?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, по всем пунктам