# Выдает ошибку, когда пытаюсь зайти в /wp-admin на хостинге

Tags: wordpress

пытаюсь зайти на хостинге в **wp-admin/** и выдает ошибку: **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**
Сам сайт работает и все корректно отображается, но при этом ошибку выдает если пытаюсь перейти на **/wp-admin/**

Кэш чистил. в **wp-config.php** написал три строчки, но все равно ничего не поменялось. Сделал бекап, когда была возможность зайти в админку, но все равно ничего не помогло.

```
define('WP_SITEURL','MY-SITE_URL');
define('WP_HOME','MY-SITE_UR');
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Без конкретных адресов это гадание.. Вангую неправильный перенос на https и использование костлей типа really simple ssl. А эту фигню надо удалить из конфига.

Comment: @SeVlad Вот к этой админке нету доступа https://mid-mabat.co.il/wp-admin/

Comment: Там дорвей. https://bertal.ru/index.php?a8809581/https://mid-mabat.co.il/wp-admin/#h сайт взломан. см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040