# Ошибка при вроде в админку. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

При заходе в админу выдает такую ошибку, и никак в админпанель не заходит. В чем проблема может быть?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_admin() in /var/www/u1306360/data/www/megawayco.com/wp-admin/profile.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/u1306360/data/www/megawayco.com/wp-admin/profile.php on line 17

Answer (score 2):

> `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_admin() in /var/www/u1306360/data/www/megawayco.com/wp-admin/profile.php:17  Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/u1306360/data/www/megawayco.com/wp-admin/profile.php on line 17`

Испорчено ядро.
В [wp-admin/profile.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/profile.php) нет `is_admin()`

Возможно это результат [взлома](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777040)