# На сайте появляется папка wp-admin, хотя сайт не на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, вирусы

С какого-то момента на сайте начали появляться папка wp-admin, в которой один файл
aXZhbm92by16b3YucnU6NDQz.txt.

Подозреваю, что это вирус. Что это может быть за вирус? Как лечить?

Сайт тестовый еще пока.

Comment: Написано про ВП, но многие пункты не зависят от движка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/Вирусы-в-wordpress/777040#777040

Comment: Похоже на вот это https://inwebpress.ru/japanese-seo-hack/ пару месяцев назад вычищал от этого с десяток сайтов, папка wp-admin тоже появлялась не только на WP сайтах и были такие же файлы с рандомными именами.

Comment: Это не случайное имя @Simon, это base64 encode поэтому имя кажется непонятным, если декодировать название файла в текущем случае то получается: **ivanovo-zov.ru:443**