# Назначение сайту Wordpress темы

Tags: wordpress

Нашел wordpress тему - [Wordpress Theme](http://wp-templates.ru/creativ-mag/). Загрузил в админ панель сайта Mywpsite.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в результате получаю следующий внешний вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы на сайте отображалась страница как на скриншоте темы?
Изначально сайту была назначена тема Twenty Twenty-One.

Comment: Ну так активация темы, не наполняет Ваш сайт изображениями и контентом. Если внутри темы нет опиции импорта демо контента, то все это нужно будет настроить и заполнить руками.

Comment: Потеряй эту вирусню https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040