# Как появляется этот вирус? (Centos 7/Apache/Nginx)

Tags: php, wordpress, сервер, вирусы

Имею VDS с CentOS 7, Вебсервер Apache MPM-Prefork/Nginx, на нем 5 сайтов, 2 из которых на wordpress (последние версии, постоянно обновляю).

Периодически антивирус ImunifyAV находит файлы в папке site.com/wp-admin/user с похожим названием help-tabs-Az0nZP.php. (примерное содержание этих файлов ниже).

Что делал – менял пароли везде (root, админка), менял права доступа к .htaccess и wp-config.php на 440. Обновления вроде вставлю ядра итп, все автоматически обновляется.

Не могу понять, как эти файлы появляются и где дыра.

```
<?php
    $string = 'p1qi/LukEIMREd...A8PPE0XLog';
    $ktmp = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/pleWebk(.*) \(/is',$ktmp,$kk)){
        $key = $kk[1];
        $key = str_replace('/','p@',$key);
    }else{
        die();
    }
...
```

Comment: Не надо распространять код вирусов через такой высокопосещаемый сайт, как StackOverflow. Я убрал код, достаточно показать лишь начало.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040

Comment: Извиняюсь, думал может по коду будет понятно, откуда он берется.

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы могут быть в нескольких местах.

1. "5 сайтов, 2 из них WordPress". Если php код на всех сайтах выполняется под одним пользователем Linux, то заражение может идти с любого сайта. Достаточно взломать самописный php-сайт (а это распространённый случай), и с него уже можно вносить изменения в соседние сайты.
2. Права доступа. Владелец файлов WP сайта должен быть тот пользователь, под которым выполняется php. Права - 755/644 на файлы/папки.
3. Избегайте самописных тем и плагинов - их авторы, как правило, не имеют представления о том, что такое безопасный код. Пользуйтесь решениями из официального репозитория WordPress.
4. Исключите использование взломанных тем или плагинов - это почти 100% гарантия того, что в них содержатся вирусы и бэкдоры (а вы думали, их взламывают из альтруизма?).
5. Установите Wordfence плагин - он обеспечит непрерывный мониторинг и защиту WP сайта.
6. Смените все пароли администраторов WP сайтов на надёжные. Заражение сайта может идти через банальную утечку пароля.

Comment: Кем код выполняется не выяснил, но он генерирует тысячи каких-то страниц, похожих на aliexpress. Самописных сайтов нет, другие на dle. права на папки все проверил, такие и ставил, не изменились. Плагины ставил только с репозитория. ЗА плагин спасибо, стоит iThemes Security , но что-то не то показывает)
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не кем выполняется, а под каким юзером исполняется php. Можно так попробовать в консоли `php -r "echo exec('whoami');"`