# Wordpress. Реально ли взломать хостинг из-за слабого пароля в админку сайта?

Tags: wordpress, безопасность, хостинг, уязвимости

Установили на хостинг сайт со слабым паролем в админку. Сайт работает на Вордпрессе.
Спустя несколько дней безопасность хостинга обнаружила вирусные файлы в каталоге сайта, которых при установке не было.
Возможен ли вариант, что файлы каким-то образом занесли на хостинг через взломанную админку CMS?

Comment: Такой вариант возможен. Так же это могло произойти, если плагины/темы на Вашем сайте не обновлены до актуальных версий, либо используете "nulled" (типа пиратский) тему/плагин. Ну и есть ряд других возможностей, как можно внедрить вредоносный код к Вам на сайт, в зависимости от того что там используется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможен ли вариант, что файлы каким-то образом занесли на хостинг
> через взломанную админку CMS?

Попав в админку и с правами администратора можно сделать всё, что позволяет php на котором работает сайт. Т.е. можно установить плагин, изменять и создавать файлы и далее по цепочке.

Но вирусы зачастую проникают не так, а через варезные плагины и темы. См [подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040)

Answer (score 0):

если неправильно настроены права (к примеру пользователь выкладывает сайт под root) то возможно, вирусы могут подняться по директориям выше основного сайта только если это позволят права пользователя.