# Очень необычный редирект или как это работает?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, редирект

есть сайт http://duxlegem.com/
при прямом входе (вводе в адресную строку доменного имени) - все ок, попадает куда надо.
но если ввести в гугле duxlegem.com и нажать на ссылку - то попадает на странный магазин https://lovesluga.xyz/, в чем причина и как убрать этот редирект? первый раз такое вижу, хостер и доменный регистратор открещиваются, в htaccess тоже нет проблемы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При наличии слова `google` в HTTP-заголовке `Referer` сервер отвечает пустой страницей, содержащей в себе js-код `window.location = "https://lovesluga.xyz/";`. А уж откуда взялся этот js-код на сервере — видимо, ищите как-то сами

Comment: У тебя вирь, определяющий рефферер. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040