# Странные ссылки в гугле на сайт в домене .ru

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, seo, ссылки

Имеется сайт и при поиске его в Гугле, я вижу вообще текст которого у меня в принципе нет. Вот если вы перейдете на сайт, то вы увидите, что информация другая
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А может быть такое, что когда-то раньше существовал такой домен и он просто не подгрузился?

Comment: Нет, сайт мой и у него имеется сертификат, а вот в Гугле мой сайт дает такую информацию, но у меня даже ссылок таких нет

Comment: Да, это мой сайт. Тебе скрин хостинга показать?

Comment: Вот и речь идет, какого куя в Гугле идет вообще левый текст

Comment: Этот сайт я делал для них и при поиске заметил вот такое

Comment: Почему я что-то должен тебе доказывать? Я задал прямой вопрос, а получаю ответ вообще не по моему вопросу.

Comment: [убрать из индекса гугла ссылки](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4496786/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82?hl=ru)

Comment: в яндексе такой ерунды нет..

Comment: был неправ, проапдейтил метки, может кто из сеошников что-то присоветует

Comment: Возможно, вас взломали, ищите вирусню на хостинге. А возможно, это следы древнего дорвея со времён когда это был ещё и не ваш сайт.

Comment: Кстати, держите страницу как она выглядела для гугла в мае 2023: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yxJD7_maxjcJ:khp86.ru/ieawhhcvbxppgk-78/&cd=10&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru  Это точно взлом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040

Comment: Это с самого начала было. Я не думаю, что взлом. Я смотрел sitemap и там были ссылки. Щас сделал свой, пока без изменений

Comment: У меня вот есть второй сайт самопис, там почти такая же картинка

Comment: @Express а зря не думаете. Вордпрессы боты ломают все подряд в автоматическом режиме. Если у вас есть вордпресс с незакрытыми дырками - он уже взломан, тут вариантов нет.