# Перезаписывается файл .htaccess в папке wp-admin и при удалении появляется снова

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Перезаписывается файл .htaccess в папке wp-admin и при удалении появляется снова. Из-за него не могу зайти в админ-панель wordpress, вместо админ-панели отображается белый экран.
Код в файле:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-theme.php|wp-scripts.php|wp-editor.php|mah.php|jp.php|ext.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Вирусня какая-то. Лечить надо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-wordpress/777040#777040