В WordPress до тега html автоматом добавляется вирусный код
<script src="//cdn.csyndication.com/"></script><script src="//sync.gsyndication.com/"></script> вот такой код добавляется на сайт перед <!DOCTYPE html>. Из-за этого периодически сайт редиректит куда зря. Если смотреть через консоль, то в head первыми идут три строчки:
<script async="" src="https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.csyndication.com/"></script>
<script src="//sync.gsyndication.com/"></script>

Что это может быть за вирусяка и как с ним бороться?
Тема - купленная. Плагины - все официальные. Ядро - переустанавливал. Отключал все плагины - не помогает ничего. Я сталкивался с разными вирусами, ну тот - просто перед всем стандартным кодом html вставляет скрипт! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777029/%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-wordpress - все из списка перепробовал, ничего не помогает. Потому и написал эту тему, так как ничего похожего не нашел по форуму.

Этот вопрос похож на: Вирусы в WordPress. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

@Simon как по мне, вы даже не пытались разобраться в проблеме человека. Он ясно описал свою проблему. Другое дело что его вопрос требует небольшого дополнения. Об условиях хостинга и настроек PHP.

@EugeneX это ты не читал ни этот вопрос ни по ссылке.

Во первых "купленаня тема" - не гарантия чистоты (скорее наоборот, если производителя нет в репо) Во вторых редиректы кешируются. Поэтому проверять их нужно не в браузере, а сервисами. В третьих по ссылке написаны и другие причины.

@EugeneX данную проблему невозможно решить без того чтобы хотя бы пройтись по некоторым файлам и просмотреть директории на наличие подозрительных файлов, которые могут маскироваться под плагины или под файлы ядра и так далее, потому разобраться без доступа к серверу, довольно проблематично.

3 минуты поиска: https://oguzturk.net/wordpress-virus-infecting-wp-config-php/ https://moesec.com/blog/research/analysis-of-a-newly-found-malicious-javascript-on-wordpress-sites/
Все расписано. Ставить moesec не рекомендую - первый раз вижу. Отзывов в Сети нет.
Надо попробовать вычистить сначала с помощью Wordfence - это проверенное решение на миллионах сайтов.

@KAGGDesign спасибо, поизучаю. Мне поиск ничего не выдал... Я ж перед тем, как написать, сделал все стандартное - переустановил ядро, БД проверил, файлы подозрительные поискал, антивирусом прошелся. Wordfence ничего не нашел вообще

@Simon - это не стыдно признаться, что ты просто ничего не знаешь и кидаешь тему, где взагали по загалям аля "если вдруг что-то - сделайте все подряд" и пофиг, что я описал четко проблему, а все то, что в той ветке про вирусы помогает примерно как мертвому расслабляющий массаж.

@ІванКірсанов а ну хорошо, как скажете) Подскажете пожалуйста, каким образом Вам помочь, по трем строкам кода и инормации о том что это добавляется автоматически перед <!DOCTYPE html>?) Или Вы ожидали ответа, что бы я указал в каком конкретно файле Вам нужно посмотреть? Похоже на лечение по фото.

В последний раз когда я сталкивался с подобным, это маскировалось под плагин с названием search-optimizer и просто вешало Base64 кодированный JS в head темы, подобных эксплойтов могут быть тысячи или десятки тысяч, они могут иметь различные реализации и так далее.

@Simon я ожидал ответа от людей, которые сталкивались вот прям с подобной хренью. Потому что все разы, когда раньше бывали вирусы - помогало разное и очень часто даже банальная выгрузка сайта и прогон через антивирус - помогало. А в этот раз не помогает ничего - ни обновление ВП, ни восстановление резервной копии до вируса (сайта и БД), ни чистка БД, ни удаление плагинов. Вот прям вообще глухо по всем фронтам. И я впервые вижу вот такой вот вирус - когда код встраивается ДО вообще всего html. И я написал как раз в надежде, что кто-то сталкивался прям с такой же хренью недавно

А с чего ты взял что это вообще вирус? отключи Яндекс Метрику и уберутся и эти файлы тоже.
Вот смотри файл... http://cdn.csyndication.com/
Цитирую...
(function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){

Это Яндекс шифрует так свои шпионские программы :D
А внешний сервер, потому что это CDN. Их используют просто для кеширования больших файлов по мировым сетям.
Если Яндекс Метрику подключал не ты и код лезет ДО/После документа HTML то возможно это хостинг пихает тебе в сайт свою дрянь.
Этим очень часто страдают бесплатные Хостинги.
Они как правило через этот код проверяют посещаемость сайта через Metrika API https://yandex.ru/dev/metrika
Если есть доступ к .htaccess то можно попробовать отлючить дерективы PHP
; Automatically add files before PHP document.
; https://php.net/auto-prepend-file
auto_prepend_file =

; Automatically add files after PHP document.
; https://php.net/auto-append-file
auto_append_file =

Вот такой вот строкой в .htaccess
php_value include_path "."
php_value auto_prepend_file ""
php_value auto_append_file ""

Если сисадмин хостинга не очень опытный и не отключил это, то вполне заработает.
Но тебе могут заблокировать сайт, так как я почти уверен что это нарушает правила бесплатного хостинга.
Ps: Еще посмотри этот сайт, там все 4 дерективы управления PHP из .htaccess - https://ma.ttias.be/php-php_value-vs-php_admin_value-and-the-use-of-php_flag-explained/

Это вирус уже потому, что этого нет и не должно быть ни в ВП ни в чистых плагинах и темах. А тот факт что его добавляет (если это действительно так) какой-то говнохостинг не делает его не вирусом. (А про случайные редиректы ты вообще не прочитал)

@SeVlad про случайные редиректы я думаю что это скорее последствие событий. Суде по нику человек из UA. А там соответственно Yandex в глубоком бане. И при попытке счетчику Яндекс пытаться загрузиться, происходит редирект. Но я не могу гадать на кофейной гуще. Я описал предположительно свое мнение почему этот счетчик может лезть в сайт и скорее жду что ответит Іван Кірсанов. Я не могу утверждать что я прав, это тупо. Но если я вдруг прав, то это может исправить и остальные проблемы.

Ты лучше ничего не пиши, если вопрос касается ВП... (думает он.. оох..)
